# What's the difference between python shebangs with /usr/bin/env rather than hard-path?

Tags: python, path, environment, shebang

I used to use the shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

When is it better to use

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

What is the exact difference between them?

Comment: Did you try `man env`  to see what the `env` app does?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do people write #!/usr/bin/env python on the first line of a Python script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script)

Comment: @S.Lott I assumed `env` was a directory, not an executable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I put #! (shebang) in Python scripts, and what form should it take?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`#!/usr/bin/python` is hardcoded to always run `/usr/bin/python`, while `#!/usr/bin/env python` will run whichever `python` would be default in your current environment (it will take in account for example `$PATH`, you can check which python interpreter will be used with `which python`).

The second way ( `#!/usr/bin/env python` ) is preferred , as it's not dependent on particular installation. It will work for example with `virtualenv` setups or systems where there is no `/usr/bin/python`, but only e.g. `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Comment: This. See [Why do people write #!/usr/bin/env python on the first line of a Python script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2429511/668807) and [this message on the Python mailing list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2007-June/054828.html).

Comment: Indirection via `env` also works when `/usr/bin/python` exists, but isn't an actual executable (e.g. it may be a launch script)

Comment: does that imply that it is better to use `#!/usr/bin/env perl` will be more versatile than the usual shebang `#!/bin/perl`? It seems to me that people usually use `#!/bin/perl` in perl, but `#!/usr/bin/env python` for python. Why?

Comment: @Ken, no principled reason, just accidents of history.

Comment: @Ken: AFAIK, there isn't popular equivalent of virtualenv for Perl.