# Hadoop streaming crashes in the middle of map/reduce operation

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I'm using hadoop 1.0.1 on a single node and I'm trying to stream a tab delimited file using python 2.7.  I can get Michael Noll's word count scripts to run using hadoop/python, but can't get this extremely simple mapper and reducer to work that just duplicates the file.  Here's the mapper:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    print '%s' % line
```

Here's the reducer:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    print line
```

Here's part of the input file:

```
1   857774.000000
2   859164.000000
3   859350.000000
...
```

The mapper and reducer work fine within linux:

```
cat input.txt | python mapper.py | sort | python reducer.py > a.out
```

but after I chmod the mapper and reducer, move the input file to hdfs and check that it's there and run:

```
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-*streaming*.jar -file mapperSimple.py -mapper mapperSimple.py -file reducerSimple.py -reducer reducerSimple.py -input inputDir/* -output outputDir
```

I get the following error:

```
12/06/03 10:19:11 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
12/06/03 10:20:15 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful. Error: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201206030550_0003_m_000001
12/06/03 10:20:15 INFO streaming.StreamJob: killJob...
Streaming Job Failed!
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do your python files have the [shebang / hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) headers? I imagine your problem is when Java comes to execute the mapper python file, it's asking the os to execute the file, and without shebang / hashbang notation, it doesn't know how to execute the file. I would also ensure your files are marked with executable permissions (`chmod a+x mapperSimple.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    print '%s' % line
```

Try this from the command line to ensure the shell knows to execute the files with the python interpreter:

```
cat input.txt | ./mapper.py | sort | ./reducer.py > a.out
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris.  My brain always ignores lines with the comment symbol, so I ended up spending 20 hours cutting back my code and trying every variation I could think of.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Chris White Answer, the shebang header should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

which will use python2.7 by default. if you want to use python3, you can use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

And DO NOT use:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Because it would fail on most computers.. including mine ****sigh****

Check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take) for more info