# Why is `input` in Python 3 throwing NameError: name... is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, input, eval

I have a string variable `test`, in Python 2.x this works fine.

```
test = raw_input("enter the test") 
print test
```

But in Python 3.x, I do:

```
test = input("enter the test") 
print test
```

with the input string `sdas`, and I get an error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/ananiev/PycharmProjects/PigLatin/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    test = input("enter the test")
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
NameError: name 'sdas' is not defined
```

Comment: I had the same issue when using a Terminal with python2 while writing the code in python3

Comment: your `print test` statement is not Python 3.x: It should be `print(test)`. As it is, python is trying to evaluate test as a command.

Answer (score 14):

You're running your Python 3 code with a Python 2 interpreter. If you weren't, your `print` statement would throw up a [`SyntaxError`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SyntaxError) before it ever prompted you for input.

The result is that you're using Python 2's [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input), which tries to `eval` your input (presumably `sdas`), finds that it's invalid Python, and dies.

Comment: Python 3 input function is well explained in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7Y9ugHJJUg.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say the code you need is:

```
test = input("enter the test")
print(test)
```

Otherwise it shouldn't run at all, due to a syntax error. The `print` function requires brackets in python 3. I cannot reproduce your error, though. Are you sure it's those lines causing that error?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. In the terminal when I typed "python filename.py", with this command, python2 was tring to run python3 code, because the is written python3. It runs correctly when I type "python3 filename.py" in the terminal. I hope this works for you too.

Comment: Or use the shebang in the python script :). More info, for example, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take

Answer (score 1):

In operating systems like Ubuntu python comes preinstalled. So the default version is python 2.7 you can confirm the version by typing below command in your terminal

```
python -V
```

if you installed it but didn't set default version you will see

```
python 2.7
```

in terminal. I will tell you how to set the default python version in Ubuntu.

A simple safe way would be to use an alias. Place this into **~/.bashrc** or **~/.bash_aliases** file:

```
alias python=python3
```

After adding the above in the file, run the command below:

`source ~/.bash_aliases` or `source ~/.bashrc`

now check python version again using `python -V`

if python version 3.x.x one, then the error is in your syntax like using **print** with parenthesis. change it to

```
test = input("enter the test")
print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

sdas is being read as a variable. To input a string you need " "

Comment: Are you sure? As far as I did understand, the OP wants zu pass a defined variable so the script does evaluate the variable.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you wants to say? It would be better if you provide code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

```
temperature = input("What's the current temperature in your city? (please use the format ??C or ???F) >>> ")

### warning... the result from input will <str> on Python 3.x only
### in the case of Python 2.x, the result from input is the variable type <int>
### for the <str> type as the result for Python 2.x it's neccessary to use the another: raw_input()

temp_int = int(temperature[:-1])     # 25 <int> (as example)
temp_str = temperature[-1:]          # "C" <str> (as example)

if temp_str.lower() == 'c':
    print("Your temperature in Fahrenheit is: {}".format(  (9/5 * temp_int) + 32      )  )
elif temp_str.lower() == 'f':
    print("Your temperature in Celsius is: {}".format(     ((5/9) * (temp_int - 32))  )  )
```

Answer (score -1):

If we setaside the syntax error of print, then the way to use input in multiple scenarios are -

If using python 2.x :

```
then for evaluated input use "input"
example: number = input("enter a number")

and for string use "raw_input"
example: name = raw_input("enter your name")
```

If using python 3.x :

```
then for evaluated result use "eval" and "input"
example: number = eval(input("enter a number"))

for string use "input"
example: name = input("enter your name")
```