# Im trying to input string in python can you teach me please

Tags: python

I’m new at programming. How can I get an error message if I input a string, using an `if else` statement in Python.

```
x = int(input("Enter the no."))

if (x>5):
    print (x ,'Is greater than 5')
elif (x==str):enter code here
    print('Incorrect input')
elif (x==5):
    print (x ,'Is equal to 5')
elif (x<5):
    print (x ,'Is less than 5')
else:
    print (x ,'none of the above!')
```

Comment: enter anything non numeric into the input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input string in python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625669/input-string-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're studying Python, but either your source is awful or you're jumping too ahead.

**Problems**

1. Converting your input to `int`
   In Python 3, any user input you receive through the `input()` function is considered to be a `string`. Therefore, when you do `x = input()`, the type of `x` is `string`. By wrapping the `input()` function with the `int()` function, you're converting this output, which is supposed to be a `string`, to an `int`.
   .
2. When you check conditions, you compare `x` directly to `str`, which will *not* work. `str` is a `string class` while `x` is its instance. If you want to compare the two, you'd obviously have to use the `type()` function - `type(x) == str`.

Comment: Can you recommend good tutorial video that i can download to learn python ?

Comment: No need to be sorry, I taught myself Python as well so I was just recommending that you take baby steps first. Also no I can't, I initially used Codecademy like everyone else.. lol