# My while loop keeps looping keeps repeating even when the user inputs the correct information

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I know the site has some answered strings about my query but they don't help. I am making this program where the admin knows the password and when asked for the password if the password is wrong it will ask them to enter the password until they get it correct.

```
admin_password = input("To view a user's details, enter the admin pasword: ")
while True:
    if admin_password != "AdminLogin":
        print("Incorrect password")
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the admin_password to inside the loop

```
while True:
    admin_password = input("To view a user's details, enter the admin 
pasword: ")
    if admin_password != "AdminLogin":
        print("Incorrect password")
    else:
        break
```

Right now you are taking admin_password once and are repeatedly checking it against the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop seems fine. I think your problem is in taking input. Are you running a Python 3 code with a Python 2 interpreter? See this: [input string in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625669/input-string-in-python-3). By the way, you can use this piece of code. Works fine by me.

```
admin_password = raw_input("To view a user's details, enter the admin pasword: ")

while admin_password != "AdminLogin":
    admin_password = raw_input("To view a user's details, enter the admin pasword: ")

print "Logged In"
```

Comment: oh , my bad. I'm using Python 2.7. you're right. raw_input doesn't work on Python 3