# env: python\r: No such file or directory

Tags: python, macos, osx-mountain-lion, shebang, env

My Python script `beak` contains the following shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

When I run the script `$ ./beak`, I get

```
env: python\r: No such file or directory
```

I previously pulled this script from a repository. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The script contains CR characters. The shell interprets these CR characters as arguments.

Solution: Remove the CR characters from the script using the following script.

```
with open('beak', 'rb+') as f:
    content = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(content.replace(b'\r', b''))
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: @NiklasR, See [the screencast](http://asciinema.org/a/5973) I just recorded. The error message is slightly different because I recorded it in Linux machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your screencast. I understand the problem now :)

Comment: @downvoter, Any reason for downvoting this? How can I improve the answer?

Comment: And by "CR" we mean "carriage return" (ASCII 13).

Comment: I just resolved that issue. 
Your current file is "CR" type or any thing else, so you have to open that file by notepad++ or any editor and convert that to "LF".
Notepad++: Edit menu -> EOL Conversion -> Unix (LF), and then save that Pic:
https://i.imgur.com/paAPYsK.png

Hope it useful for you guys.

Comment: any idea how these characters got there in the first place?

Comment: @embulldogs99, Windows use CR, LF for line ending. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#History

Answer (score 103):

Open the file in **`vim`** or **`vi`**, and administer the following command:

```
:set ff=unix
```

Save and exit:

```
:wq
```

Done!

### Explanation

`ff` stands for *[file format](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format)*, and can accept the values of `unix` (`\n`), `dos` (`\r\n`) and `mac` (`\r`) *(only meant to be used on pre-intel macs, on modern macs use **`unix`**)*.

To read more about the `ff` command:

```
:help ff
```

`:wq` stands for **W**rite and **Q**uit, a faster equivalent is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>zz</kbd> (i.e. hold down *Shift* then press `z` twice).

Both commands must be used in [command mode](http://www.radford.edu/%7Emhtay/CPSC120/VIM_Editor_Commands.htm).

> <sup>*offtopic*: if by chance you are stuck in vim and need to exit, [here](https://github.com/hakluke/how-to-exit-vim) are some easy ways.</sup>

### Usage on multiple files

It is not necessary to actually open the file in vim. The modification can be made directly from the command line:

```
 vi +':wq ++ff=unix' file_with_dos_linebreaks.py
```

To process multiple `*.py` files (in `bash`):

```bash
for file in *.py ; do
    vi +':w ++ff=unix' +':q' "${file}"
done
```

While it looks innocent, the bash syntax above will break on file names containing spaces, quotes, dashes, etc, a more reliable alternative that will also process subfolders would be:

```bash
find . -iname '*.py' -exec vi +':w ++ff=unix' +':q' {} \;
```

### Removing the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) mark

Sometimes even after setting unix line endings you might still get an error running the file, especially if the file is executable, has a [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19305076/191246), and you are running it without prefixing it with `python`. The script might have a BOM marker (such as `0xEFBBBF` or other) which makes the shebang invalid and causes the shell  to complain. In these cases `python myscript.py` will work fine (since python *can* handle the BOM) but `./myscript.py` will fail when the execution bit is set because your shell (sh, bash, zsh, etc) *can't* handle the BOM mark. (It's usually windows editors such as *Notepad* that create files with a BOM mark.)

The BOM can be removed by opening the file in `vim` and administering the following command:

```bash
:set nobomb
```

Comment: Used this on both `pdf2txt.py` and `dumppdf.py` which i installed by `pip install pdfminer.six` on my Ubuntu machine. Now errors are gone and they work as they should

Answer (score 26):

You can convert the line ending into *nix-friendly ones with

```
dos2unix beak
```

Comment: This worked for me. I got this error when trying to run ~/leo-5.0/launchLeo.py to open the Leo editor.

To get it to work, I had to install dos2unix first using Homebrew like so: `brew install dos2unix`

Answer (score 14):

If you use PyCharm you can easily solve it by set the line separator to LF. See my screenshot.
[image: As you can see you can set it at the bottom right corner]

Comment: didnt work for me

Answer (score 4):

I cured this error by running python3, ie
python3 \path\filename.py

Comment: I suspect that the python script was developed on Windows which has different line endings from Unix/Linux: Windows uses \r\n; Unix and Linux use \n. If you edit the file, try removing the \r at the end of the first line and then “./beak” should work.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of falsetru did absolutely solve my problem. I wrote a small helper that allows me to normalize line-endings of multiple files. As I am not very familar with the line-endings stuff on multiple platforms, etc. the terminology used in the program might not be 100% correct.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Copyright (c) 2013  Niklas Rosenstein
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
# all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
# THE SOFTWARE.

import os
import sys
import glob
import argparse

def process_file(name, lend):
    with open(name, 'rb') as fl:
        data = fl.read()

    data = data.replace('\r\n', '\n').replace('\r', '\n')
    data = data.replace('\n', lend)
    with open(name, 'wb') as fl:
        fl.write(data)

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Convert line-endings of one '
            'or more files.')
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--recursive', action='store_true',
            help='Process all files in a given directory recursively.')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--dest', default='unix',
            choices=('unix', 'windows'), help='The destination line-ending '
            'type. Default is unix.')
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--is-expr', action='store_true',
            help='Arguments passed for the FILE parameter are treated as '
            'glob expressions.')
    parser.add_argument('-x', '--dont-issue', help='Do not issue missing files.',
            action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('files', metavar='FILE', nargs='*',
            help='The files or directories to process.')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Determine the new line-ending.
    if args.dest == 'unix':
        lend = '\n'
    else:
        lend = '\r\n'

    # Process the files/direcories.
    if not args.is_expr:
        for name in args.files:
            if os.path.isfile(name):
                process_file(name, lend)
            elif os.path.isdir(name) and args.recursive:
                for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(name):
                    for fn in files:
                        fn = os.path.join(dirpath, fn)
                        process_file(fn, fn)
            elif not args.dont_issue:
                parser.error("File '%s' does not exist." % name)
    else:
        if not args.recursive:
            for name in args.files:
                for fn in glob.iglob(name):
                    process_file(fn, lend)
        else:
            for name in args.files:
                for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk('.'):
                    for fn in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dirpath, name)):
                        process_file(fn, lend)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vscode or pycharm, set the end of line sequence to LF. This solves it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the first solution using vi / set ff=unix, but it didn't work.  I found a very very simple way of solving it:

I opened the python file in the text editor Mousepad (on a R Pi), selected Document/Line Ending, and changed it from "DOS / Windows (CR LF)" to "Unix (LF)", then saved it.  It's possible I also re-typed the shebang at the top, can't remember.  It works now.