# While trying to build android source code, make clobber gives "no such file or directory"

Tags: android, bash, android-source

Before I start, I have tried all the other answers but nothing seems to work.
For example: [env: python\r: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425857/env-python-r-no-such-file-or-directory).

I am building android source code on OS X El Capitan and I get this error when i run the command "make clobber".

> env: python\r: No such file or directory
>   /bin/bash: out/soong/soong: No such file or directory
>   make: *** [run_soong] Error 127

**soong** is a symbolic link. I have executed the command dos2unix on the target file. 
[image]

what am i missing ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a python script has a shebang line (the `#! ...` line) terminated by a carriage return `\r` that is interpreted as part of the `python\r` name. It  could be related to your second error. I suspect that the erroneous python script is supposed to generate `soong.bash`. Note: instead of using screen shots, please copy-paste the error messages and format them properly.

Comment: A `\r` at the end of a line means that the file was created with a DOS/Windows editor.  Run a utility like `dos2unix` over the file.

Comment: @john1024 I did do that on song.bash. That is the file you are talking about right ?

Comment: From the screen capture, the name of the file that contains `python\r` is not clear to me.  But, if you edited any of the files on Windows, running `dos2unix` over them is a good idea.  (Some editors on Windows are good at respecting Unix line endings.  Others are not.)

Comment: I downloaded everything directly to my laptop. I did not edit any of the files on windows. I followed google's instruction and was successful until i got to this part. I even uninstalled everything and did everything from scratch carefully but still ended up at the same error.
https://source.android.com/source/building.html
Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @TheA8nova The error message indicates that `env` was looking for a program named `python\r` and, of course, there is no such program.  The `\r` might have been mistakenly left in a file uploaded to the website.  It is also possible that, in the process of downloading the file, `\r` characters were added.  Whatever the cause, the `\r` do not belong there and `unix2dos` is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my error by dos2unix-ing from the source directory. It took a little longer than 30 minutes but then it worked!
something likes this from the source tree :

**find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 4 dos2unix**