# How to Make my R script executable?

Tags: r, shebang, rscript

I am aware this is at high risk of being a duplicate, but in none of the other questions here I have found an answer to my problem. Below is a summary of what I have already tried.

I have an R script file `file.r`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript 
print("Hello World!")
```

which is executable (`chmod +x file.r`), and which used to run nicely (last time I used it was about a month ago) by issuing:

```
$ ./file.r
```

However, today:

```
$ ./file.r
/usr/bin/env: 'Rscript\r': No such file or directory
```

In fact:

```
$ which Rscript
/usr/bin/Rscript
```

Thus I changed shebang to: `#!/usr/bin Rscript`, but:

```
$ ./file.r
/usr/bin: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

Then I thought I would run it as super user, but:

```
$ sudo ./file.r
sudo: unable to execute ./file.r: Permission denied
```

Reading around I found that a fresh installation of R would solve my problem, so I un-installed and installed R. Unfortunately what I have written before still applies. Notice however that the following works with both shebang versions:

```
$ Rscript file.r
[1] "Hello World!"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin Rscript` definitely doesn't make sense. I think you were trying to do something like `#!/usr/bin/Rscript` to make a direct path to the executable. That would work if that's where Rscript is stored for you.  It seems to me that the "\r" portion of the original error is what is causing the issue.  Have you tried deleting the entire shebang line and retyping it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ah, Its carriage return (\r) issue, It's added to the first line, if you are using vi editor, `:set list` will show it. line endings will be shown as $ and carriage return chars as ^M.

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript  Makes your script portable than #!/usr/bin/Rscript
```

Btw, you can insert \r in vi by going into insert(i)/Append(a) mode and type ctrl+v and then ctrl+m

Comment: That was the case, thanks. For future reference of emacs users: you can show end of lines by doing: `M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system` and choosing `utf-8-unix`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to point directly to the executable, then you need the full path after the shebang (no space):

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
```

As Ravi pointed out, if this fix doesn't work then the solution may just involve deleting the line break and putting it in again.

I'm not a fan of the `env` workaround to make things more portable, because it makes the line more confusing and most people don't realise that it's actually calling another program (i.e. `env`) to run the code in a modified shell. More information on that [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my#29620).

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I've found is here: [env: python\r: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425857/env-python-r-no-such-file-or-directory)

```
Open the file in vim or vi, and administer the following command:

:set ff=unix

Save and exit:
:wq

Done!
```