# Getting error as :- env: 'python3\r': No such file or directory While running pyspark project using Docker in windows10

Tags: python, windows

Getting error while running pyspark project using Docker in windows 10:

> env: 'python3\r': No such file or directory

Python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Tried the following ways:

1. unix2dos - Converted the file in dos format using a linux box and downloaded the file from linux box to windows local machine.
2. Sublime Text3 - Saved the file as a python file and then tried running it, but same error.

Reference:

1. [env: python\r: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425857/env-python-r-no-such-file-or-directory)
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/896860/usr-bin-env-python3-r-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to create a new file.   Copy the buggy  file (issue with 'python3\r') and pasted in a normal file without the "#!/usr/bin/env python3".  Then save it with the .py extention and type by hand (without copy paste) "#!/usr/bin/env python3".