# Why is Code Runner using the old 2.7.1 version of Python instead of 3.x on OSX?

Tags: python, macos, vscode-code-runner

I am trying to use the newer version of Python but when I type:

```
import sys
print sys.version_info
```

I get back:

```
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

In the terminal when I enter `python` I get:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
```

When I enter `python3` I get:

```
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 13 2013, 13:52:24) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

As you see, I have installed Python 3.3 but no matter what I do I can't seem to actually use it in Code Runner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CodeRunner->Preferences->Languages->Run Command

edit "python $filename" to "python3 $filename"

Comment: in newest VSCode for MAC need to modify the "code-runner.executorMap" setting set python: "python3"

Answer (score 19):

For the latest version of VS Code, you need to open settings (shift+command+p) and override the python interpreter value under `code-runner.executorMap`.

[image: vscode settings showing modification of the "python" setting inside "code-runner.executorMap"]

Answer (score 7):

In new versions of the settings.json file, just enter:

> "code-runner.

(Note the `"`) and it should show an auto-complete list (or you can press ctrl+space) and select `"code-runner.executorMap"`. It should show all of the run commands. Change:

```json
"python": "python -u",
```

to

```json
"python": "python3 -u",
```

To change your IntelliSense for error handling in python3, open the Command Palette (ctrl+shift+P) and select "Python: Select interpreter" and select python 3.x.x.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing Python's "run command" in the [preferences](http://timmyomahony.com/assets/posts/virtualenv-codeapp-f30fb7fcc8394dc558dc984bff136b7b.png) to:

```
python3 $filename;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>, (comma)</kbd> to open the **Preferences**, and then make sure the **Languages** of **Python3** have this:

[image]

BTW, use `which python3` to make sure the path is `/usr/local/bin/python3` instead of `/usr/bin/python3` to ensure safety

Comment: Why is `/usr/bin/python3` unsafe? I don't use Mac. Is it because it might be outdated/unpatched? Or is it just that `/usr/local/bin/python3` is the path where Brew installs it or something like that?

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3` comes with the system, if you change it randomly, some system files based on it will make mistakes, `/usr/local/bin/python3` is downloaded by yourself, you can do whatever you want

Comment: Who's talking about changing it?

Comment: You can do some things more safely with the `/local/` path. It is difficult to guarantee that sometimes you don’t need to reinstall python or something

Answer (score 0):

Crate a python file and get current sysinfo

```
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```

#### Need to change to python3?

1. open your vscode settings file

   1. mac: `command+shift+p`
   2. search for `openSettingsJson`
2. locate the `python` attribute in the json object
3. change the value to `python3`
4. validate results by running the aforementioned file
5. profit

Answer (score 0):

Another STUPID but working hack is to set Alias in your Shell.

What Code Runner basically does is
*python -u filename.py*

But if you goto your Shell Config file and add one line at your config file(possibly .bashrc/.zshrc or whatever you use)

i.e

```
alias python='python3'
```

now whenever coderunner executes

```
python -u filename.py
```

it is actually executing

```
python3 -u filename.py
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, though I'm using Linux. It seems to depend on your config, cause if I enable `code-runner.runInTerminal`, then it works (since it's running in a shell). Or, I believe if Bash is your login shell, then it might work depending on your Bash config; I just can't remember how that works exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The command `python` refers to Python 2 on MacOS and other systems (probably following [PEP 394](https://peps.python.org/pep-0394/)).

To run your script with Python 3, one option is to add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) as the first line in the file, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6908143/4518341):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Code Runner will use the shebang, following the setting `code-runner.respectShebang`.