# how do I create a file that I can execute (has execute permissions)

Tags: python, file-permissions, chmod

I am creating a file with the `open(file.py,"w"`) command.
The `file.py` that is created has read and write permissions but I cannot exceute it.

What is the best way to create a file that I can run afterwards?

Should I, after creating the file and closing it, use `os.chmod(file.py,0777)`?

Comment: You already answered your question. Why wouldn't you just try it? It would have taken far less time than asking here!

Comment: If filenames are string literals, need quotes they do.

Comment: I wanted to see if there is a way to do it in one command. Does open(file.py,attr) has a an attribute for executable?

Comment: Don't forget to add an appropriate [shebang](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6908143/2870069)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for [open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), there is no attribute that specifies execution privileges.  Instead, use `chmod`, as you mentioned in your question, but avoid using magic numbers and don't give all privileges to all users unless you know what they might do.

```
import os
from stat import S_IEXEC

file_name = "something_good.py"

with open(file_name, "w") as fp:
    write_something_to_file(fp)

os.chmod(file_name, S_IEXEC | os.stat(file_name).st_mode)
```