# pytest module not found

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, pytest

I'm having trouble running `pytest` on my package.  I have the following structure...

```
 tree -f
.
├── [   0 Jan  4 22:04]  ./__init__.py
├── [ 34K Jan 12 11:37]  ./LICENSE
├── [1.4K Jan  6 07:43]  ./README.md
├── [1.1K Jan 12 11:42]  ./setup.cfg
├── [  79 Jan  6 08:22]  ./setup.py
├── [4.0K Jan 12 11:49]  ./tcx2gpx
│   ├── [ 701 Jan  6 23:13]  ./tcx2gpx/__init__.py
│   ├── [4.0K Jan 12 12:13]  ./tcx2gpx/__pycache__
│   │   ├── [ 683 Jan 12 12:13]  ./tcx2gpx/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── [3.0K Jan  6 21:00]  ./tcx2gpx/__pycache__/tcx2gpx.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── [3.1K Jan 12 11:49]  ./tcx2gpx/tcx2gpx.py
├── [4.0K Jan  4 21:52]  ./tests
│   ├── [4.0K Jan  6 06:32]  ./tests/resources
│   │   ├── [288K Jan  6 21:07]  ./tests/resources/2019-10-20 12:51:21.0.gpx
│   │   └── [816K Jan  4 22:03]  ./tests/resources/2019-10-20 12:51:21.0.tcx
│   └── [4.0K Jan 12 12:24]  ./tests/tcx2gpx
│       ├── [ 386 Jan 12 12:17]  ./tests/tcx2gpx/conftest.py
│       ├── [   0 Jan 12 11:48]  ./tests/tcx2gpx/__init__.py
│       └── [1.3K Jan 12 12:24]  ./tests/tcx2gpx/test_tcx2gpx.py
└── [4.0K Jan  6 06:21]  ./tmp
    ├── [288K Jan  6 06:21]  ./tmp/2019-10-20 12:51:21.0.gpx
    └── [ 415 Jan  5 08:38]  ./tmp/test.py
```

And my `conftest.py` has the follwoing...

```
"""
Fixtures for test_tcx2gpx
"""
from pathlib import Path
import pytest

from tcx2gpx.tcx2gpx import TCX2GPX

TCX_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1]
TCX_FILE = TCX_DIR / 'resources' / '2019-10-20 12:51:21.0.tcx'
GPX_FILE = TCX_DIR / 'resources' / '2019-10-20 12:51:21.0.gpx'


@pytest.fixture
def tcx_file():
    """
    Fixture of TCX file
    """
    return TCX2GPX(TCX_FILE)
```

On running `pytest` from the top-level I'm informed...

```
____________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test session ____________________________________________________
/home/neil/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:458: in _importconftest
    return self._conftestpath2mod[key]
E   KeyError: PosixPath('/mnt/work/python/tcx2gpx/tests/tcx2gpx/conftest.py')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
/home/neil/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:464: in _importconftest
    mod = conftestpath.pyimport()
/home/neil/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:701: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/home/neil/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:143: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
tests/tcx2gpx/conftest.py:7: in <module>
    from tcx2gpx.tcx2gpx import TCX2GPX
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tcx2gpx.tcx2gpx'
```

Reading around I found a few threads on this (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722212/python-cant-find-module-in-the-same-folder)) and because I'm working on CI on GitLab I decided to try modifying the `PYTHONPATH` (as I can put these as part of the `script` that is executed on GitLab CI execution)...

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:."
python -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"
['', '/mnt/work/python/tcx2gpx', '/home/neil/.virtualenvs/default/lib64/python
36.zip', '/home/neil/.virtualenvs/default/lib64/python3.6', '/home/neil/.virtualenvs/default/lib64/python3.6/lib
-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/home/neil/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python3.6/site-pac
kages', '/mnt/work/python/python-tcxparser']
pytest
```

But I get the same error, even though `/mnt/work/python/tcx2gpx` where the above directory structure is located, is in the `PYTHONPATH`.

I have also tried using `python -m pytest` because, as stated [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2287#issuecomment-284200894) doing so should automatically include the current directory in `syspath`.  I get the same result though, `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I also found [this article](https://medium.com/@dirk.avery/pytest-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-requests-a770e6926ac5) which describes conflicts between a system installed `pytest` and that within a virtual environment, but firstly I can not uninstall it at the system level because its a required dependency of other packages I have installed in the system, and secondly I get the same error when trying to run the tests in GitLab CI where I don't think there is any other version of `pytest` installed (I have to explicitly install it as part of the testing stage).

Really stumped on why this isn't working any suggestions or pointers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does it show up in `pip list`?

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't have an `__init__.py` file at the top of your project -- this is causing pytest to assume that the parent directory is the root of your project

deleting that fixes it for me

(disclaimer: I'm a pytest core dev)

Comment: Also incorrect import statement `from tcx2gpx.tcx2gpx import TCX2GPX ` needs to be changed.

Comment: @wim from the filestructure that looks fine, there's `tcx2gpx/tcx2gpx.py` (it's a little confusing because OP used `tree -f` instead of normal `tree`)

Comment: Ah, you're right. My bad. Seems like one-too-many levels of namespaces than necessary though.  And a `tcx2gpx` package under tests is confusing things more.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the top level `__init__.py` but that didn't make any difference.  Removing the `__init__.py` that was within the `tests/tcx2gpx` directory and running `python -m "pytest"` solved it.  Thanks for the pointer.  I'm still confused about the need for `__init__.py` as I thought it was a [hangover from Python <3.3*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/448279/1444043) but perhaps I don't have namespaces working properly, something to read up on!

Comment: Annoyingly removing `__init__.py` from the test folder introduces a `F0010` on linting but I can work on eliminating that.

Comment: yeah they are optional, however pytest still uses them to figure out project roots -- if you add `__init__.py` all the way up your tree (not at the root) that'll solve that too -- another option is to move your tests outside of your package and then you only need `tests/__init__.py`