# Module not found error in pytest when tests folder contains __init__.py

Tags: python, pytest

My tests were working a few hours before. But suddenly tests located in root folder/tests are giving me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests.test_*` I imported the tests.test_a in a top level python file and it worked. Any guesses why cant pytest load them?

I am asking this because this is weird that the test folder located inside root folder/some folder/tests also contains `__init__.py` and they work fine. I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59703976/pytest-module-not-found) and deleted the `__init__.py` and it worked. But it is confusing as to why the top level tests would not work.

The folder structure is along the lines of:

```
.
├── authenticate
│   ├── exceptions.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── exceptions.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── repository.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   └── use_case.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── Readme.md
│   ├── repository.py
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── test_authenticate.py
│   └── use_case.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── test_authenticate.cpython-38-pytest-5.4.2.pyc
│   ├── test_authenticate.py
```

Answer (score 1):

As weird as it sounds, I had forgotten to add `__init__.py` in one of my packages. I don't know why it was causing tests in my top level directory to fail