# Receiving following error when trying to write Python3 program: NameError: name 'util' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to write a Python code and keep getting the following error message, `*** NameError: name 'util' is not defined` for this snippet of code. Cannot figure out the problem.

code

```
import itertools
import random
import busters
import game

from util import manhattanDistance, raiseNotDefined

def getBeliefDistribution(self):
        """
        Return the agent's current belief state, a distribution over ghost
        locations conditioned on all evidence and time passage. This method
        essentially converts a list of particles into a belief distribution.

        This function should return a normalized distribution.
        """
        "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
        beliefDistribution = util.Counter()

        for particle in self.particles: #in particle list
            beliefDistribution[particle] += 1 #weighing all the particles
        beliefDistribution.normalize() #normalizing

        return beliefDistribution #returns distribution

        #util.raiseNotDefined()
```

Error Message:

```
*** FAIL: Exception raised: name 'util' is not defined
*** 
*** Traceback (most recent call last):
***   File "/home/trno224/Documents/CS463G:Introduction_to_artificial_intelligence/Project3/grading.py", line 78, in grade
***     util.TimeoutFunction(getattr(gradingModule, q),1800)(self) # Call the question's function
***   File "/home/trno224/Documents/CS463G:Introduction_to_artificial_intelligence/Project3/util.py", line 633, in __call__
***     result = self.function(*args, **keyArgs)
***   File "autograder.py", line 309, in <lambda>
***     return lambda grades: question.execute(grades)
***   File "/home/trno224/Documents/CS463G:Introduction_to_artificial_intelligence/Project3/testClasses.py", line 80, in execute
***     if not f(grades):
***   File "autograder.py", line 304, in <lambda>
***     return lambda grades: testCase.execute(grades, moduleDict, solutionDict)
***   File "trackingTestClasses.py", line 179, in execute
***     run(self.layout_str, pac, ghosts, disp, maxMoves=self.maxMoves)
***   File "trackingTestClasses.py", line 272, in run
***     games = busters.runGames(lay, pac, ghosts, disp, nGames, maxMoves)
***   File "/home/trno224/Documents/CS463G:Introduction_to_artificial_intelligence/Project3/busters.py", line 542, in runGames
***     game.run()
***   File "/home/trno224/Documents/CS463G:Introduction_to_artificial_intelligence/Project3/game.py", line 607, in run
***     agent.registerInitialState(self.state.deepCopy())
***   File "trackingTestClasses.py", line 424, in registerInitialState
***     self.distCompare(inf.getBeliefDistribution(), dists[index])
***   File "inference.py", line 366, in getBeliefDistribution
***     beliefDistribution = util.Counter()
*** NameError: name 'util' is not defined
***
```

Comment: Where's the `util.py` file? Same folder as this code? Or is it some library?

Comment: @KevinLanguasco In same folder as code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python can't find module in the same folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722212/python-cant-find-module-in-the-same-folder)