# How to call a function from one Python file to another in the same directory

Tags: python, spyder

I am trying to figure out how to reference a function in a `.py` file from another `.py` file in the same directory.  I have followed the python.org Modules instructions, but I can't get it to work.

Here is what I have so far:

This is the file `mymodule.py' that contains the function:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define plus_two function
def plus_two(x):
    print(x+2)
```

Here is the file that calls the function:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import mymodule
x=4
mymodule.plus_two(x)
```

It should print 6, but it just gives this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodule'`

The `mymodule.py` file has been saved, and I know the function works fine.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are you sure you have those files in the same folder? Are these files part of a bigger project structure?

Comment: @pacuna They are not part of a larger structure.  It's literally just those two .py files.  I am using Spyder, and I have them both saved on my desktop if that matters.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722212/python-cant-find-module-in-the-same-folder) might help

Comment: Figured it out.  Turns out I was pressing `Shift+Enter`, which works great in Jupyter notebooks but doesn't work in Spyder when not using `#%%` to break the code into cells...