# Extending gdb with python: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, debugging, gdb, modulenotfounderror

I have a python script, which is extending gdb for C debugging. I run `gdb project_name/gdb/target.elf` to start gdb. I'm on Windows 10 using the cygwin terminal. When i'm in the gdb console I type `source project_name/gdb/debug.py`. In my debug.py file I have a class StartupHandler:

```
class StartupHandler(gdb.Command):
    def __init__ (self):
        super (StartupHandler, self).__init__ ("startup-handler", gdb.COMMAND_NONE)
    def invoke (self, args):
```

which is getting inizialized using the code `StartupHandler()`. After that I can run `startup_handler args` in the gdb console which calls the `invoke()` method, that makes some initialization. After that I can debug my target.

Now I would like to factor out some global variables I'm using in `project_name/gdb/debug.py` in an additional file called `project_name/gdb/debug_data.py` and import the global vars like `from debug_data import var1`

By importing the global vars from the new file I'm getting the Error:

```
 File "c:\current\share\gdb/python\gdb\__init__.py", line 130, in _execute_file
    exec(compiled, globals, globals)
  File "project/gdb/debug.py", line 17, in <module>
    from debug_data import var1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debug_data'
```

when I type in `source hymap/gdb/debug.py` in the gdb console.
Does anyone know why the python interpreter inside gdb throws the ModuleNotFoundError?

Comment: What's the code on line 17 of `project/gdb/debug.py`?

Comment: For `import` to be able to find `debug_data`, you need to have `'project_name/gdb'` in Python's `sys.path` list. Try `sys.path.append('project_name/gdb')`.

Comment: @ssbssa from debug_data import var1

Comment: @MarkPlotnick You might want to post it as answer (or close as duplicate of [Python can't find module in the same folder - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722212/python-cant-find-module-in-the-same-folder) ? Although I don't know if gdb Python environment makes the relative import different)