# Python Module not recognized in same folder

Tags: python, module, init

I'm trying to import my class `ODSFileExtractor`from my file `ods_extractor.py` into my `main.py`.

For that reason I have an `__init__.py` in my `odsrw` folder where I import the class.

However, I seem unable to use my module inside my `main.py`, as I get an `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odsrw'` when I try to run the file.

My `__init__.py` inside `odsrw`:

```
from .ods_extractor import ODSFileExtractor

__all__ = ['ODSFileExtractor',]
```

My `main.py`:

```
from odsrw import ODSFileExtractor


def main():
    
    file_extractor = ODSFileExtractor()
    file_extractor.extract()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My file structure:

```
src
└───odsrw
    │   main.py
    │   ods_extractor.py
    │   ods_reader.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    └───sqlite_data
            db_functions.py
            db_setup.py
            models.py
            __init__.py
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using ` from .odsrw import ODSFileExtractor` with '.' operator before module name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python can't find module in the same folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722212/python-cant-find-module-in-the-same-folder)

Comment: did you try to use `from .ods_extractor import ODSFileExtractor` or `from . import ODSFileExtractor` instead of `from odsrw import ODSFileExtractor` . To use `import odsrw` you would have to add path `src` to environment variable `PYTHONPATH` or to `sys.path` (in code before `import`)

Comment: @furas The sys.path.append('./src') did it, all other options you suggested unfortunately aren't recognized by Python. I don't know why that's the only way, but if it's like that I think my project structure altogether may be flawed.