# python local file module not found but with cli finds module

Tags: python

This is my `file.py`:

```py
import os
os.chdir('/home/python3.10')
print(os.getcwd())
print(os.system('pwd; ls'))
import template
print(template.text)
```

I have a virtual environment in `/home/python3.10`.

If I run file like this:

```bash
/home/python3.10/venv/bin/python3.10 /home/another_dir/file.py
```

I get this error:

```
/home/python3.10
/home/python3.10
__pycache__  file1.txt  requirements.txt  template.py  test.py  venv
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/another_dir/file.py", line 5, in <module>
    import template
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'template'
```

But if I run `/home/python3.10/venv/bin/python3.10` in the shell, then I run all of above lines, it works:

```
Python 3.10.13 (main, Aug 25 2023, 13:20:03) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>>
>>> os.chdir('/home/python3.10')
>>> print(os.getcwd())
/home/python3.10
>>> print(os.system('pwd; ls'))
/home/python3.10
__pycache__  file1.txt  requirements.txt  template.py  test.py  venv
0
>>> import template
>>> print(template.text)
{text}
```

What's the reason I have this error? I see the `getcwd()` is the correct directory, but I'm not sure why it cannot see `template.py` to import as module.

Comment: Generally, your modules should be kept in a fixed location independent of your script location. Make your code installable, so that `template.py` gets installed to your virtual environment's `lib/site-packages` directory, and your script gets install to your virtual environment's `bin` directory.

Comment: @chepner I add this command to the crontab, and `PATH=/root` when running behind the crontab. So, I need to tell where the path so `template.py` is. Do you have any idea for this?

Answer (score 1):

When you run python interactively, the default module import path is the current directory.  If you call `os.chdir()` to change the current directory, the default module import path is also updated.

But when you run a python script like this:

```
python /some/dir/myscript.py
```

The default module import path is `/some/dir`, and it **does not change**, even if you change the current directory with `os.chdir()`.

Comment: Thanks, I understood completely. Then what's the solution? I mean any other solutions than `cd /home/correct-path; /home/python3.10/venv/bin/python3.10 /home/another/filepy`.

Comment: I did what https://stackoverflow.com/a/24722419/5790653 and it's solved in my case.

Comment: I add this command to the crontab, and `PATH=/root` when running behind the crontab. So, I need to tell where the path so `template.py` is. Do you have any idea for this? What I said in the previous comment was just a workaround in this case:(