# ImportError: No module named 'Adafruit_DHT' in flask application

Tags: python, flask, sensors, adafruit

I am developing a weather station. I use a Raspberry Pi 2 as well as a DHT22 sensor. I use Adafruit to read the sensor's data. I installed it like described in their [Readme](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT). I tried both ways but unfortunately non of them worked.

Reading the data works sometimes, but it does never work when I try to read it in my Flask application

Here is my code:

```
import Adafruit_DHT
app = Flask(__name__)

sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
gpio = 4


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "This is the index page"

@app.route('/humidity', methods=['GET'])
def get_humidity():
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, gpio)
    return humidity

@app.route('/temperature', methods=['GET'])
def get_humidity():
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, gpio)
    return temperature

@app.route('/all', methods=['GET'])
def get_humidity():
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, gpio)
    return 'humidity='+humidity+';temperature='+temperature



if __name__ == 'main':
    app.run()
```

Additionally, I had a look at the following answers on Stackoverflow.com:

- [DHT22 Sensor import Adafruit_DHT error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246239/dht22-sensor-import-adafruit-dht-error)
- [DHT22 Sensor import Adafruit_DHT error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246239/dht22-sensor-import-adafruit-dht-error/26251405)

I appreciate your help!

**Update**
Adafruit works well if I disable the virtual environment

Comment: the solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514593/importerror-no-module-named-when-trying-to-run-python-script)