# I can't seem to use the input function in Python 3.3.2

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, input, quotes

I'm running Python on my mac but I'm encountering this problem.

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
name = input(’Enter name (max 60 chars): ’)

print(’Hello ’ + name + ’. Welcome’)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
File "/Users/mac/Documents/workspace/helloworld/hello.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /Users/mac/Documents/workspace/helloworld/hello.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

What do I do? I also can't use single quotes. Since I'm level 1 I can't post images, so [here's a picture of the version of my Python launcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAaFc.png).

Comment: Did you look at PEP 263 and try to put an encoding comment at the top of your file?

Comment: Is that your complete hello.py ?

Comment: That's not related to `input()`; something is wrong with your file's text encoding.

Comment: I think you should change this quote `’` to `'`

Comment: The other question, I suppose, is if a real text editor is being used, or something that does some sort of smart quoting.

Comment: It might be good to double check your Python version, and your system settings (anything related to language or encoding). Python 3 should use UTF-8 by default, but it's decided to use ASCII - the smart quote will still give an error, but it should be a *different* one ("invalid character in identifier").

Comment: After fixing your question's formatting, it's much easier to see the problem: those aren't ordinary ("straight") quotes like `'`. They're smart quotes like `’`.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this in your File and try again.

**# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-**

If you have copied and pasted the code from some other source, then I suggest you delete and re-type the single quote character(').

Comment: Where do I exactly add it?
Thank you for your response.

Comment: Just re-type the single quotes and try again first. If that doesnt help, add the coding part at the top of the file

Comment: I've used single quotes now. I inputted 'abc' as the name
but it still gives me an error, says name 'abc' is not defined

Comment: Are you sure you're using Python 3?

Comment: Yes I am. I hope.
here's a pic http://i.stack.imgur.com/aAaFc.png

Comment: Getting a "name not defined" error after `input()` is a common problem in Python 2 - could you try changing `input(...` to `raw_input(...` and see what it says?

Comment: It works perfectly with raw_input, but I'm on Python 3.3.2

Comment: @Falcon2908 If it works perfectly with `raw_input()`, you are not on Python 3.3.2. :)

Comment: I see. But why does it tell me I'm on Python 3.3.2?
How do I switch to that? I've already installed it

Comment: @Falcon2908 The system that's telling you you're on Python 3.3.2 is not the same system that is running your script. If you run your script with something like `python hello.py`, try `python -3 hello.py` instead. Or try adding a [shebang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take).

Comment: I'm new to Python too, so how do I go about it?

Comment: How are you running python? Command line? or any other tool?

Comment: I'm using eclipse. I have also installed Pydev on it. It is part of our college

Comment: Did you try replacing the single quotes in your .py file. Please change that and try running again once

Comment: Haha my friend helped me fix the problem. But thanks anyways :)