# Why is my python file not running?

Tags: python, input, output, stdout, stderr

I am trying to follow a book step-by-step but I am either getting nothing back or getting errors.

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

```
import sys

class RedirectStdoutTo:
    def _init_(self, out_new):
        self.out_new=out_new

    def _enter_(self):
        self.out_old= sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self.out_new

    def _exit_(self, *args):
        sys.stdout = self.out_old

print('A')
with open('out.log', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as a_file, RedirectStdoutTo(a_file):
    print('B')
print('C')
```

And when I run in Python, I write `python log.py`

It returns an error saying:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    python ilog.py
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are you trying to run a Python script from within the Python interpreter, using terminal-style commands?

Comment: What Operating System are you attempting to run this on?

Comment: Doing `python log.py` within the Python interpreter instead of at your OS's console/terminal is like starting your car and telling it to get you a sandwich instead of telling your friend to take your car and go get you a sandwich.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you. That was the problem.

Comment: If you want to start your script from commandline make sure you read about the Python shebang: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take

Comment: Note also that it should be `__init__` (et. al), not `_init_`. You're missing a set of underscores.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your script, but in how you invoke it. As far as I understood, you start python and then type in `python log.py`. This is **wrong** - you need to start python with `log.py` as argument, not type this in to already started Python interactive session.

If you start python from OS X terminal (or similar command-line prompt), then instead of saying `python` say `python log.py`, while you're in the same directory as your `log.py` file.

The `python log.py` command is **not** Python, but a shell command. It's meant for your OS X terminal's bash prompt, not for Python itself.

Comment: I am using OS X terminal.

Comment: I first typed in python to start it. And then to access the file, I write: python log.py

Comment: Good, then it's simple. Just type `python log.py` instead of just `python` right in OS X terminal, when you want to start Python. See, the idea is to invoke Python, giving it filename of your script as *argument*, not just starting Python (this invokes so-called interactive shell) and then trying to tell it to load something.