# Run python program from terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I have downloaded a python program from git.
This program is python 3. 
On my laptop i have both python 2.7 and python 3.4. Python 2.7 is default version.
when i want run this program in terminal it gives some module errors because of it used the wrong version.
how can i force an `name.py` file to open in an (non) default version of python.

I have tried so search on google but this without any result because of lack of search tags.
also just trying things like `./name.py python3` but with same result(error)

Comment: `python3 name.py` might work. If not you might want to have a look into 'python virtual environments' (google it) which allows you to set up a self-contained environment with specific versions of python, packagers etc, in which you could make the default version of python 3.4

Comment: python3 nameofthescript.py

Comment: If that does not work, try `/full/path/to/python3 script.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Method of @Tom Dalton and @n1c9 work for me!
`python3 name.py`

Answer (score 0):

When you type "python", your path is searched to run this version. But, if you specify the absolute path of the other python, you run it the way you want it.

Here, in my laptop, I have /home/user/python3_4 and /home/user/python2_7. If I type python, the 3.4 version is executed, because this directory is set in my path variable. When I want to test some scripts from the 2.7 version, I type in the command line: /home/user/python2_7/bin/python script.py. (Both directory were chosen by me. It's not the default for python, of course).

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the shebang `#!<path_to_python_version_you_want>`

As in:

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

at the very top of your .py file

Also checkout: [Should I put #! (shebang) in Python scripts, and what form should it take?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take)