# How to Use "./" In a Terminal Instead of "python"?

Tags: python

For me, I have to say "python my_file_here.py" to run something.  How do it make it so that I can input "./my_file_here.py"?

Thanks,
Kwow

Comment: Use a shebang at the beginning of your script, see for instance [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6908143/5257515)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a called a "shebang" line. It tells your system what to use to execute the file.

Typically, they are the first line in your module and they look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

However, you need to know where your python executable lives on your system and if you are sharing this with others, it could be problematic (their `python` may live somewhere differently than your `python`).

It's common to do something like the following on Linux systems instead, which will respect activated virtual environments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Lastly, you also need to make sure that your file is executable on its own because you won't be able to run it as a script unless it has been marked "executable".

You can check by running the following and checking the permissions (look for the `x`):

```
ls -l YOURPYTHONMODULE.py
```

Usually, you'll see three sets of permissions (all run together) which correspond to "read" (`r`), "write" (`w`), and "execute" (`x`) for three different types of users: the owner of the file, the group the file belongs to, and everyone else. Here's an example:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 YOURNAME  staff  443 Feb 15 20:44 YOURPYTHONMODULE.py
```

To make your file executable for your user, do the following:

```
chmod u+x YOURPYTHONMODULE.py
```

With the shebang line added and your file now marked as executable, you should be able to simply do:

```
./YOURPYTHONMODULE.py
```

Comment: Thank you!  I actually already had it on my computer; I was just wondering how to implement it on other computers, just in case.