# Package installed by Conda, Python cannot find it

Tags: python, anaconda, theano, conda

I try to install Theano by Anaconda. It works, but when I enter the python -i,  `import theano` shows `No module named 'theano'`. Do I need to switch another interpreter of Python, how? Also, for the packages installed by conda, if I don't double install them, can I find in Python? How is Python related to Python by Anaconda? Thanks!!!

Comment: You said "*It works*" - what do you mean by that? The installation works, or using theano works? What version of Python do you get by running `python` on the command line - what is the **full text** of the header that prints out? Finally, what operating system are you using?

Comment: The installation is successful, but I couldn't find theano package in python.  The python I use is 3.5, 32-bit, and Anaconda is the latest, 32-bit. The operating system is Windows 10. If I type {pip install theano}, it appears {Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): theano in d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages}. Thank you! @MattDMo

Comment: Please run the following in python: `import sys; print(sys.path)` and see if `D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages` is included.

Comment: After I added that to PYTHONPATH, the `import theano` works! Though it seems that there are other problem in the installation, `Theano do not support Python 3.5 on Windows.` and `Mingw` and `Python3.5*` were found to be in conflict. May I ask how to install python2.7 and python3.5 both and refer to them? Thanks a lot! @MattDMo

Comment: conda update --all   fixed the issue for me on a different package but same problem.

Answer (score 17):

I had have a similar issue, trying to install **folium**. If you are using the **Anaconda**:

When you install using `conda install -c conda-forge folium`, the package will be placed in:

```
./anaconda3/envs/[name env]/lib/python3.7/site-packages/folium
```

When you install using pip (with a anaconda env activated), `pip install folium`, the package will be placed in:

```
./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/folium
```

Python use **first** the sites-packages as the target directory of manually built python packages. When you build and install python packages from source (using distutils, probably by executing python setup.py install ), you will find the installed modules in site-packages by default.

In this case you have two places: `/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` and `/anaconda3/envs/[name env]/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`.

First the modules will be available as default in `/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`. Sometimes (and I really don't know why) the modules inside sites-packages conda env are not available to import automatically without export the PATH.

So, to solve this issue, you have 2 options:

- Installing using `pip install folium` and import folium (don't need install by conda install), or
- After conda install , run `conda init`, close the terminal and open a new one. So, try to import again.

[Here are](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) some tips about use a pip in a conda-environment.

Comment: If any one using miniconda3 got here like me, you will need to add /miniconda3/pkgs to path.

Comment: Also to anyone using miniconda3, make sure your python points to miniconda3/envs/<your_env>/bin/python

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to a specific version of python by using the following at the first line of your .py file
This is for python 2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

This is for python 3

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

As other users already pointed out you need to check if your module is included in your sys path. Use code:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

If not you can include this in your sys.path by using the command:

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/the/folder/of/your/module/file')
```

or place it in default PYTHONPATH itself.

Other great answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19305076/5381704

Comment: Yep. And there is also Python in Anaconda, when I typed Python, which one am I running? Since I added Anaconda in PYTHONPATH, are they sharing the package with each other? What about the system requirement of different packages, e.g. one for Python2.7, one for Python3.5? I am just so confused with different versions and their application. Thanks!

Comment: when you type PYTHON you use python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the code editor you are using, you are running the default interpreter. Based on your code editor, change the python interpreter to the conda interpreter and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case that happened because conda screwed up the environment variables. Instead of using env-specific `python` and `pip`, it used the globally installed ones.

Solution:

```
conda deactivate your-env
conda activate your-env
```

Comment: This didn't solve my issue, which is the same as OP

Answer (score 0):

In my workstation, I was able to solve `No module named <module name>` error using two different ways.

First method, I solved this temporarily by:

(1) Open a Terminal
(2) `$ conda activate <Conda environment name>`
(3) `$ export PYTHONPATH=/home/<user name>/anaconda3/envs/<Conda environment name>/lib/<Python package version>/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH`

It is a temporary solution. Whenever you run your virtual environment, you have to do this.

My runtime environment:
    OS: Unbuntu 18.04
    Conda version: 4.8.2
    Conda-build version: 3.18,11
    Python version 3.7.6.final.0

Second method, I removed the
`alias python=/usr/bin/python3.6` line in `bashrc` file.
Somehow this line blocks using Python tools installed in Anaconda Virtual Environment if the Python version in the Virtual Environment is different.

Answer (score 0):

Actually for Spyder: the iterator is reset to the default, and you just need to re-select the in Tool -> Preferences -> python interpreter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).