# "testpymunk.py", line 3, in <module> import pymunk # Import pymunk.. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymunk'

Tags: python, pymunk

I installed pymunk with the conda install method. It installed and is in the correct directory. From the python terminal it passes the python test program.

In either Spyder IDE or Geany IDE when I attempt to run any of the example programs from the pymunk site I receive a module not found pymunk error.

I am trying to learn python from the book "Learning Python with Raspberry Pi" but using Ubuntu 20.04 with python 3.7 installed with Anaconda.

Comment: Have you checked that you have the required modules installed for the IDEs?

Comment: I assumed that by using the conda install method that any other needed modules would be installed as well (I recall that the pymunk web site indicated that as well). Spyder IDE is part of the Anaconda distribution as well which is why I have been trying to use it with the test programs. If there are other packages needed please tell me and I will attempt to install them.

Comment: Solved this problem after reading prior posts to stack overflow. Installed pymunk with pip3 (pip3 install pymunk) and it installed another package in a different directory. This solved the problem (though I have 2 directories with pymunk now). The link that explains this is  -   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811929/package-installed-by-conda-python-cannot-find-it. Thank you all.