# Installed anaconda python libraries cannot be imported

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, site-packages

I'm setting up a Python/conda enviroment on Ubuntu. I installed some common Python libraries such as tensorflow via `conda install` or `pip install`. Via `pip show ...` I found out they are all installed in the following folder: `/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`. However, when running them in Spyder I get the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'` error message, for about every library (including `matplotlib`).

How can I fix this? I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811929/package-installed-by-conda-python-cannot-find-it) about how they apparently need to be installed in `/home/anaconda3/envs/[name env]/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` (`/home/anaconda3/envs/` is an empty folder for me). However, the quick fix mentioned doesn't work for me.

Is there some way to add `/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`, use it as default, or is their a way to reinstall packages such that they will work?

Curiously enough, I did manage to get pygrib working via `conda install -c conda-forge pygrib=2.0.1`, but I'm not sure whether this is the way to go for all packages and would like to know what this does differently.

Comment: What python interpreter is your spyder set up to use? Probably not the one at `/home/anaconda3`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller apparently `/usr/bin/python3.6`.

Comment: Then that is the problem. Spyder will need to be configured to use the version from anaconda to be able to import the modules installed there

Comment: Yeah that was the solution. I apparently had 2 Spyders installed, and only one used the conda interpreter. Thanks a lot! I you want to, post it as an answer so I can accept it.