# Mismatch between pandas version in shell and conda

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, conda

My Conda version is 4.11, and according to `conda list` my pandas version is 1.3.5. However, when I type `python3` in the command line to bring up the shell and enter

```sh
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
```

the version is 1.1.3.

The output of `which -a python3` is

```
/home/a6623/anaconda3/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

as expected. Similarly, in the shell the output of `sys.executable` is

```
/home/a6623/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

as expected. If in the python shell I write `pd.__file__` the output is

```
'/home/a6623/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py'
```

What is causing the version discrepancy?

Edit: upon further investigation, this discrepancy is also happening to other packages (e.g., networkx)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! [Package installed by Conda, Python cannot find it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811929/package-installed-by-conda-python-cannot-find-it)

Doing `conda init` then restarting the shell worked.