# Communicating with QProcess Python program

Tags: python, c++, qt, ipc, qprocess

I'm trying to get a Qt application to communicate with a python program. The most logical solution seemed to be to run a QProcess in the Qt app containing the Python code. I want to send commands using std input and if applicable read via the std output.

However, even this simple example doesn't seem to work. These two python snippets:

```
import os
import time

while True:
    print "test"
    time.sleep(2)
```

Together with the simple Qt code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
    process = new QProcess(this);
    process->start("/home/user/test.py");

    connect(process, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QProcess::ProcessState)), SLOT(printProcessStatus()));
    connect(process, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)), SLOT(printProcessError()));
    connect(process, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(printProcessOutput()));
}

void MainWindow::printProcessStatus()
{
    qDebug() << process->state();
}

void MainWindow::printProcessError()
{
    qDebug() << process->errorString();
}

void MainWindow::printProcessOutput()
{
    qDebug() << process->readAll();
}
```

Doesn't print anything. It does say that the process is "QProcess::ProcessState(Running)", but I can't seem to get the printed output from python into Qt. Similarly I've tried to use the QProcess::write() function to write to a python process but that doesn't work either.

Is this not the intended way to work with QProcess? Is there a better way to do communication between a Qt app and a (child) python program?

Comment: That was the name of the variable in my code. I changed some explicit names to something more generic for illustration.

Comment: Try putting the `connect` statements *before* the call to `start` -- you're possibly missing some of the signals.

Comment: It does add the 'Starting' state, but it still doesn't provide the expected output of 'test' every 2 seconds.

Comment: Is the python code shown the complete script?  I don't see any `#!/usr/bin/python` or similar at the top.  What happens if you execute `test.py` at a command line?

Comment: the shebang I'm using is #!/usr/bin/env python2 (as adviced here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take). I have given the file execute permission (chmod +x) and it does print the expected output when executed in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be the way in which `python` buffers `stdout` (it's not line buffered).  The code you posted works for me if I change the script to...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import os
import sys
import time

while True:
    print "test"
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(2)
```

There's probably a better way to achieve the same thing without having to explicitly flush the stream constantly.

Alternatively, if you are on Linux, you could use [`stdbuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) to control the output buffering of the script.  Change the process start command to...

```
process->start("stdbuf", QStringList() << "--output=L" << "/home/user/test.py");
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for figuring this out, flushing stdout is more than adequate for my use case!