# Name not defined error python when reading file line by line

Tags: python, loops, variables, io

So, I am very new to python and I am not sure if my code is the most effective, but would still be very appreciative if someone could explain to me why my script is returning the "name not defined" error when I run it. I have a list of 300 gene names in a separate file, one name per line, that I want to read, and store each line as a string variable.

Within the script I have a list of 600 variables. 300 variables labeled name_bitscore and 300 labeled name_length for each of the 300 names. 
I want to filter through the list based on a condition. My script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
with open("seqnames-test1-iso-legal-temp.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        exec("b="+line+"_bitscore")
        exec("l="+line+"_length")
        if 0.5*b <= 2*1.05*l and 0.5*b >= 2*0.95*l:
            print line
ham_pb_length=2973
ham_pb_bitscore=2165
g2225_ph_length=3303
cg2225_ph_bitscore=2278
```

etc. for the length and bitscore variables.

Essentially, what I am trying to do here, is read line 1 of the file "seqnames-test1-iso-legal-temp.txt" which is ham_pb. Then I use wanted to use the exec function to create a variable b=ham_pb_bitscore and l=ham_pb_length, so that I could test if half the value of the gene's bitscore is within the range of double its length with a 5% margin of error. Then, repeat this for every gene, i.e. every line of the file "seqnames-test1-sio-legal-temp.txt".

When I execute the script, I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "duplicatebittest.py", line 4, in <module>
    exec("b="+line+"_bitscore")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ham_pb' is not defined
```

I made another short script to make sure I was using the exec function correctly that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/pin/python
name="string"
string_value=4
exec("b="+name+"_value")
print(name)
print(b)
```

And this returns:

```
string
4
```

So, I know that I can use exec to include a string variable in a variable declaration because b returns 4 as expected. So, I am not sure why I get an error in my first script.

I tested to make sure the variable line was a string by entering

```
#!/usr/bin/python
    with open("seqnames-test1-iso-legal-temp.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            print type(line)
```

And it returned the line

```
<type 'str'>
```

300 times, so I know each variable line is a string, which is why I don't understand why my test script worked, but this one did not.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: `line` includes the line terminator. you have to use `line.rstrip()`

Comment: So, to clarify, should line 2 be replaced with `for line.rstrip() in f`?

Comment: no. See my answer (and accept it if it works for you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take) question for more explanation.

As Jean pointed out, exec is not the right tool for this job. You should be using dictionaries, as they are less dangerous (search code injection) and dictionaries are easier to read. Here's an example of how to use dictionaries taken from the python documentation:

```
>>> tel = {'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139}
>>> tel['guido'] = 4127
>>> tel
{'sape': 4139, 'guido': 4127, 'jack': 4098}
>>> tel['jack']
4098
>>> del tel['sape']
>>> tel['irv'] = 4127
>>> tel
{'guido': 4127, 'irv': 4127, 'jack': 4098}
>>> list(tel.keys())
['irv', 'guido', 'jack']
>>> sorted(tel.keys())
['guido', 'irv', 'jack']
>>> 'guido' in tel
True
>>> 'jack' not in tel
False
```

Here's a way I can think of to accomplish your goal:

```
with open("seqnames-test1-iso-legal-temp.txt") as f:
    gene_data = {'ham_pb_length':2973, 'am_pb_bitscore':2165,
                 'g2225_ph_length':3303, 'cg2225_ph_bitscore':2278}
    '''maybe you have more of these gene data things. If so,
    just append them to the end of the above dictionary literal'''
    for line in f:
        if not line.isspace():
            bitscore = gene_data[line.rstrip()+'_bitscore']
            length = gene_data[line.rstrip()+'_bitscore']
            if (0.95*length <= bitscore/4 <= 1.05*length):
                print line
```

I take advantage of a few useful python features here. In python3, `5/7` evaluates to `0.7142857142857143`, not your typical 0 as in many programming languages. If you want integer division in python3, use `5//7`. Additionally, in python `1<2<3` evaluates to `True`, and `1<3<2` evaluates to `False` whereas in many programming languages, `1<2<3` evaluates to `True<3` which might give an error or evaluate to `True` depending on the programming language.

Comment: This seems to work for the most part because it prints 4 expected results, but then gives me an error: `KeyError: '_bitscore'`

Comment: Your file probably has some whitespace at the end. The `KeyError` means that you tried a dictionary lookup and it failed. On the line `bitscore = gene_data[line.rstrip()+'_bitscore']`, `line.rstrip()` is the empty string on some iteration. Python then runs it as `bitscore = gene_data[''+'_bitscore']` which is the same as `bitscore = gene_data['_bitscore']`. To fix it, put `if not line.isspace():` after the for loop and before the assignment statement (and change indentation accordingly). This checks that the line is not all whitespace characters. I changed my original answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

`line` is yield by the text file iterator, which issues a newline for each line read.

So your expression:

```
exec("b="+line+"_bitscore")
```

is passed to `exec` as:

```
b=ham_pb
_bitscore
```

Strip the output and that will work

```
exec("b="+line.rstrip()+"_bitscore")
```

provided that you move the following lines *before* the loop so variables are declared:

```
ham_pb_length=2973
ham_pb_bitscore=2165
g2225_ph_length=3303
cg2225_ph_bitscore=2278
```

Better: quit using `exec` and use dictionaries to avoid defining variables dynamically.

Comment: I now just get the error `NameError: name 'ham_pb_bitscore' is not defined`. Could that be because it is defined after the block of code? If not, I'll try to rewrite it using a dictionary because I have read elsewhere that using exec this way isn't the best practice.

Comment: yes, move the block above. but yes, using exec isn't the best practice. And it's rather unsafe (if you don't control what's in the file, that could lead to code injection)