# My python script works well if it is run as python script.py but not when run as ./script.py

Tags: python, python-2.7

My python version is

> Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on
>   linux2 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more
>   information.

### This is my python script:

```
  def main():
          print " Generating Initial data"
  if __name__ == '__main__':
          main()
```

If i run it as,

```
/test$ python gen_in_data.py

 Generating Initial data
```

it is working fine.

But if I run it as ,

```
/test$ ./gen_in_data.py
./gen_in_data.py: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./gen_in_data.py: line 1: `def main():'
```

it is throwing this error.
Please let me know the issue.

Comment: This error almost certainly means your shell is running the script, rather than the Python interpreter. By default, executable script are run by the shell; you need a shebang line to specify a different interpreter—in this case, probably `/usr/bin/env python` or less commonly a hardcoded path like `/usr/local/bin/python`. (I'm sure this is a dup of an existing question, which will have a more detailed answer that explains things better… just let me find it.)

Comment: See this answer for info on the shebang line: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429517/6481442

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take) also has some good information.

Answer (score 0):

add this at the beginning of the file it is a special comment

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*-coding: utf-8-*-
```

Comment: Why? To make sure that his script won't run if Python is in `/usr/local/bin`, and since nobody's explained to him what this means, he'll be unable to debug it? Or to make sure it's an error if his code isn't in UTF-8?