# set path for command line of python (mac)

Tags: python, command-line, path

I defined some command line tools of python (take mycmd.py as an example), and saved them in the folder `~/Scripts`. Hence, I have to type (for example) `python /Scripts/mycmd.py -o v`. It is tedious to repeat the name of the folder `/Scripts`. I want to run the command only inputting `python mycmd.py -o v`, even without `cd`. How should I do? Add a path to the original one?

PS: in mac

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a better solution:

- put the `~/Scripts` folder in your `PATH`.
- make sure that your scripts have the correct *shebang* for python (ex: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, more details in [Should I put #! (shebang) in Python scripts, and what form should it take?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take))
- make your scripts executable (`chmod a+x ~/Scripts/*.py`)

Then you can call your scripts like any other tool (without `python` prefix), ex:

```
mycmd.py -o v
```

On Windows, you don't even need a shebang, since `.py` files are seen as launchable files, associated with the installed python interpreter. Putting the dir in the path is enough.

Answer (score -1):

Add the path to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: this will not work . python running from shell from what i understand - op meant, manipulating PTHONPATH will not help in this case

Comment: @AbhishakeGupta ddor is right. I set PYTHONPATH in ~/.zshrc, but it did not work.

Comment: add the full absolute path to that directory.