# How does zsh interpret non-absolute paths in shebangs? (WAS: Why does python3 -i permit non-absolute paths in shebang?)

Tags: zsh, shebang

I recently discovered the `-i` argument to Python, which [drops into interactive mode](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-i) after the script completes. Pretty neat!

```
$ cat test.py
#!python3 -i

x=5
print('The value of x is ' + str(x))
$ ./test.py
The value of x is 5
>>> print(str(x+1))
6
>>> 
zsh: suspended  ./test.py
```

However, when I tried to copy this script to a version that terminates on completion, it fails:

```
$ cat test1.py
#!python3

x=5
print('The value of x is ' + str(x))
$ ./test.py
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '
x=5
print('The value of x is ' + str(x))
': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

From some [further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19305076/1040915), I discovered that I had originally made a mistake, and `#!/usr/bin/env python3` is the correct shebang.

However, I'm curious why a non-absolute path to `python3` succeeds *only* when I give the `-i` flag. I guess this must be something to do with how `zsh` interprets non-absolute shebangs, but I don't know enough to know how to investigate that.

System setup: MacOS 10.12.6, iTerm2 3.1.6, zsh 5.2. `which python3` gives `/usr/local/bin/python3`, and that directory is on `$PATH`.

Interestingly, I don't get the same behaviour on sh:

```
$ sh
sh-3.2$ cat test.py
#!python3

x=5
print('The value of x is ' + str(x))
sh-3.2$ ./test.py
sh: ./test.py: python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

---

I got some comments suggesting that this is something to do with CWD or permissions. `python3` is not in my CWD, and both files have execute permission:

```
$ ls -al | grep 'py' | awk '{print $1, $10}'
-rw------- .python_history
-rwxr-xr-x test.py
-rwxr-xr-x test1.py
```

Comment: Python has nothing to do with this. Your shell is responsible for shebang.

Comment: OK, fair enough - so, let me rephrase my question. "Why does zsh behave in such a way that a non-absolute path to python3 works as expected sometimes, but not others?"

Comment: You are not doing your experiment correctly. Try again without changing your current working directory in process. Shebang works (1) with an absolute path and (2) with a path relative to CWD. `$PATH` or command line arguments play no role in it.

Comment: I have no idea what's up with test1 though. No execute permission?

Comment: I got the same result with or without -i. as obviously it shouldn't be a reason for locating an interpreter while executing your code. and kept my file permission 777. 
its your local environment, nothing to do with python

Comment: @n.m., sorry, I don't understand your comment - I didn't change my cwd, no `cd` in examples above. I added a snippet demonstrating that python3 is not on my cwd and that test1.py has execute permission

Comment: Sorry I wasn't precise, see my answer for detailed info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your kernel will not execute the script unless the interpreter is

- specified as an absolute path, or
- specified as a path relative to the current working directory

Then if the kernel refuses to execute the script, your shell *might* take over and try to execute it anyway, interpreting the shebang line according to its own rules (like finding the executable in the `$PATH` for example).

`zsh` does attempt to do this. `sh` does not.

However the way `zsh` interprets the shebang (and probably subsequent lines) is really really strange. It looks like it always expects a *single* argument after the command name. See what it does:

```
$ cat test.py 
#!python3 -b -i 

x=5
print('The value of x is ' + str(x))
$ strace -f -e execve zsh
execve("/bin/zsh", ["zsh"], 0x7ffd35c9e198 /* 78 vars */) = 0
host% ./test.py 
strace: Process 5510 attached
[pid  5510] execve("./test.py", ["./test.py"], 0x558ec6e46710 /* 79 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5510] execve("/usr/bin/python3", ["python3", "-b -i", "./test.py"], 0x558ec6e46710 /* 79 vars */) = 0
[pid  5510] execve("/usr/lib/python-exec/python3.4/python3", ["/usr/lib/python-exec/python3.4/p"..., "-b -i", "./test.py"], 0x7fffd30eb208 /* 79 vars */) = 0
Unknown option: - 
usage: /usr/lib/python-exec/python3.4/python3 [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.
[pid  5510] +++ exited with 2 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=5510, si_uid=1000, si_status=2, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
host% 
+++ exited with 2 +++
```

See how `["python3", "-b -i", "./test.py"]` are passed as arguments. It seems highly counterintuitive to me to lump the two switches `-b` and `-i` together, but that's what zsh does. Python obviously doesn't understand this.

When there are no arguments, the exact behaviour **depends on whether there is a space after the program name**, but is strange in either case. Check it with `strace` yourself because you are not going to believe me.

It is my understanding that zsh handling of the shebang line is just buggy.