# Run Python script repeatedly from bash

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to run this Python script:

```
import os

with open('check_door', 'r') as file:
    text_1 = file.readline()

with open('alert_check', 'r') as file2:
    text_2 = file2.readline()

if text_1 == 'locked' and text_2 == 'disabled':
    os.system('python sensor.py')
```

using this command: `watch -n 60 /home/pi/check_sensor.py`
I'm getting these errors:

```
/home/pi/check_sensor.py: 1: /home/pi/check_sensor.py: import: not found
/home/pi/check_sensor.py: 2: /home/pi/check_sensor.py: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You need the Python shebang at the beginning of your script if you want to run it as an executable, unless you run the script with the `python` command. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke the python interpreter, as you would do if you were running the script directly.

```
watch -n 60 "python /home/pi/check_sensor.py"
```

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python` would be more conventional -- that way the script itself chooses its interpreter, so you can change the interpreter without modifying anything but the script text itself.

Comment: Also, note the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the bullet point regarding questions which "*have already been asked and answered many times before*".

Comment: Looks like the "more conventional" way also works. Thank you both for helping me !