# How to get a python script to run as an executable?

Tags: python, bash, shell, command-line

I would like to run my python script as an executable from the command line, usually when I do a bash script I added this to the top of the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Then I made the script executable with:

```
chmod u+x myScript.sh
```

Is there a way to do this in python scripting? I tried something similar like:

```
#!/bin/python
```

However, this did not work.

Comment: What is `mkexec` ? Did you mean to suggest `chmod`

Comment: Python is usually installed under `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: @Inian Whoops that is the alias I use alot, I will edit my question

Comment: I'd like to add to this question [this excelent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take) related to python and shebangs.

Comment: Thanks, @LucasWieloch. That's got _much_ better info than the original dupe target, although that target's title matches this question better.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks guys, whoops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the top of your script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

depending if you want python2 or python 3