# execute python script with cron job

Tags: python, cron, execute

I'm trying to execute a python script every minute a cron job. I can execute the command using the terminal.

My script can be execute by the following comand:

```
 python /home/pi/Desktop/sensor_testing/dht11.py
```

and in sudo crontab -e I typed:

```
***** python /home/pi/Desktop/sensor_testing/dht11.py
```

any advice why this isn't working?

Comment: Use an absolute path instead of `python`: `/usr/bin/python` or `/bin/env python`

Comment: I tried this
    * * * * * /usr/bin/python 
    home/pi/Desktop/sensor_testing/dht11.py 
but it still doesn't work

Comment: My bad then, although you are missing a '/' at the start of "/home/..." but I suppose this is a typo in your copy/paste. Anyway, while looking for an answer, I found [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/449651) and [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/449652). Hopefully, you'll find something there. =)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take), it's a good explanation about adding a shebang to your python script. it will allow you to run the script easily without calling python explicitly, the only thing you need to do is add a correct python path to the shebang and your set.

**tl;dr from link:**

for running python 3 script, add this to the top of your script:

`#!/usr/bin/env python3`

or this for python 2.7

`#!/usr/bin/env python2`

Answer (score 0):

The time fields are *space-separated*, i.e.

```
* * * * * python /home/pi/Desktop/sensor_testing/dht11.py
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but It won't let me save the changes, it says that there is a mistake in the cron file...

Comment: Then there must be *another* mistake in there.

Comment: @pygo OP was using it successfully on command line - I don't intend to provide any more errors here.

Comment: I managed to space seperate the filds but it's still not working still with the    python     and with out it

Answer (score 0):

Its should be simply:

Put the absolute python path  on the top of your your script First:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python   # Just assuming this path
```

Make the File executable:

```
chmod +x /home/pi/Desktop/sensor_testing/dht11.py
```

then place in cron..

```
***** /home/pi/Desktop/sensor_testing/dht11.py
```

Comment: The file is executable and I added the python path to the script but it's still not doing anything...

Comment: @Miniex, Does it runs when running through command line? by the way that's script problem not  adding to cron.