# Python script does not run after logging into computer remotely using "Screen"

Tags: python, gnu-screen

Laptop A has python file "file1.py". Computer B has python file "file2.py". I want to remotely enter into Computer B and run the python script file2.py. I am using SCREEN, and below is my code.

```
import os 
import time

os.system('screen -S Test -d -m /dev/ttyUSB0 57600') 

time.sleep(1)

os.system('screen -S Test -X stuff "file2.py"')   
time.sleep(1)

os.system('screen -S Test -d -r')   
time.sleep(0.25) 

print "done"
```

Answer (score 1):

How did you try to run your 'remote' script?

You can try ssh session:

```
ssh user@computer_b 'python file2.py'
```

Of course, you should provide a full path to your `file2.py` script and maybe (I'm not 100% sure) a full path to a Python executable on your remote Computer B. Another option is to make your `file2.py` executable, by adding a Python "shebang line" as the first line of your `file2.py` script and setting executable bit via `chmod +x file2.py`:

[Should I put #! (shebang) in Python scripts, and what form should it take?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take)

Comment: `ssh` may need extra options depending on what `file2.py` tries to do. For example, a `-t` option is often needed when using `sudo` on the remote

Comment: I made the changed to the above code..but I still don't get what I want..its not changing directory..how do I define path with gnu-screen?????

Comment: I also did.."os.system('screen -S Test -X chdir "/home/user/desktop"') but its not changing the directory.

Comment: You don't run your `file2.py` remotely, as I see from your code. You try to launch `file2.py` script locally from your Laptop A via `screen`, but `screen` doesn't run scripts or programs remotely by itself. You should implement usage of `ssh` to run scrips remotely.

Comment: @mmv I am not using internet for serial communication as I am using RFD 900 radios. Is it possible to do SSH without internet?

Comment: I has no experience with connecting computers via serial connection, sorry.