# Batch File not Correctly Running Through CMD

Tags: python-3.x

My python script simply opens up google.

Batch Code ::

```
@py.exe "C:\Users\Hey\Desktop\C.Outlet\Computer Science\Python\TryingToScrape.py"
pause
```

Python Code::

```
#! python 3.7 
#Web Scraping

import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('www.google.com/')
```

I can't get it to work, and I this is my end result

```
C:\Users\Hey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe: can't open file '3.7': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\Users\Hey>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Works in IDLE, not through cmd I guess? Need that overflow insight

Comment: what is your file name?

Comment: I have a feeling its the comment at the top of your code...

Comment: `#! python 3.7`

Answer (score 2):

It's the line ([shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take)) `#! python 3.7` in your code. I've reproduced the error, and removing it lets the code run fine.

Original:

```
#! python 3.7 
#Web Scraping

import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('www.google.com/')
```

Working (tested):

```
#Web Scraping

import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('www.google.com/')
```