# How to run different python version based on project location?

Tags: python, cocos2d-x

My system is 5.0.9-2-MANJARO

I've already set the python scripts workaround described in [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cocos2D-X#Python_Scripts_Workaround)

```
➜  ~ cat /home/nfl/bin/python 
#!/bin/bash
script=$(readlink -f -- "$1")
case "$script" in (/opt/cocos2d-x/*)
    exec python2 "$@"
    ;;
esac

exec python3 "$@"
➜  ~ which python
/home/nfl/bin/python
➜  ~ echo $PATH
/home/nfl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin:/home/nfl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/cocos2d-x/tools/cocos2d-console/bin:/opt/cocos2d-x/tools/cocos2d-console/plugins/plugin_package:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin
➜  ~
```

When I run python script that output current python version, it output python2 in directory specified in the script(/opt/cocos2d-x/*) and python3 in non specified dir. So everything work fine now.

The problem is when I try to run sdkbox(cocos2d plugin) with **PATH**, it seem like python3 is used instead of python2.

```
➜  ~ which sdkbox
/opt/cocos2d-x/tools/cocos2d-console/plugins/plugin_package/sdkbox
➜  ~ sdkbox
RuntimeError: Bad magic number in .pyc file
➜  ~
```

But when I run it directly from the directory, it works

```
➜  plugin_package pwd
/opt/cocos2d-x/tools/cocos2d-console/plugins/plugin_package
➜  plugin_package ./sdkbox 
  _______ ______  _     _ ______   _____  _     _
  |______ |     \ |____/  |_____] |     |  \___/ 
  ______| |_____/ |    \_ |_____] |_____| _/   \_
 Copyright (c) 2016-2018 SDKBOX Inc. v1.0.2.8
usage: sdkbox [-h] [-v] [-p [PROJECT]] [-b [PLUGIN]] [-D SYMBOL] [-i INPUT]
              [-o OUTPUT] [-q] [-d [DAYS]] [-l LEGACY] [--key KEY] [--dryrun]
              [--forcedownload] [--noupdate] [--alwaysupdate] [--patcherrors]
              [--nopatching] [--nopatchingcpp] [--jsonapi] [--forcecopy]
              [--mkey MKEY] [--mvalue MVALUE] [--local] [--remote]
              [--info INFO] [--runin RUNIN] [--apitoken APITOKEN]
              [--silenttime SILENTTIME] [--projectpath PROJECTPATH]
              [--platform PLATFORM]
              {import,info,update,forget,restore,list,clean,symbols,version,set,tracking,encrypt,decrypt}
sdkbox: error: too few arguments
➜  plugin_package
```

What happen exactly and how to fix this?

Comment: Solved [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518628/how-to-run-different-python-version-based-on-project-location/518803#518803) Thanks for all suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Shebang might be your solution. It addresses the python interpreter by the shebang.

[Should I put #! (shebang) in Python scripts, and what form should it take?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using virtual environment for this purposes.
[virtualenv](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)