# "Can't find a default python" When executing python script through OS.system method from ColdFusion

Tags: python, coldfusion, windows-server

I have a python script on a Windows Server called optimize.py that calls three other python scripts 4 times each using the os.system() method.

```
print('Creating input files for optimization algorithm...\n')

os.system("example.py 2 2 0 1")
os.system("example.py 3 3 0 1")
os.system("example.py 4 4 0 1")
os.system("example.py -1 10 0 1")
```

This works perfectly when I execute optimize.py myself. However, when it is executed from my ColdFusion application which is running on the same server, I get the error "Can't find a default Python" each time it tries to call example.py. The rest of the script runs just fine.

This is the ColdFusion code that is executing the python script:

```
<cf_exec cmd="cmd.exe">
    cd C:\xxx_Optimization\
    "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe" [SQL_Table] out [directory] -c -t, -U [user] -P [password] -S [server]
    cd C:\xxx_Optimization\pyOptimization\
    python C:\xxx_Optimization\pyOptimization\optimize.py
    <cfoutput>#pyUniqueZipCommand#</cfoutput>
    date /t > pyDone.txt
</cf_exec>
```

I've already added python to the PATH, and I've also followed the answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57765741/how-to-fix-cant-find-a-default-python-error), to no avail. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here, or suggest an alternative to os.system for executing these scripts?

EDIT: I've also tried specifying the entire filepath in the OS.system methods, but I received the same error.

Comment: What response do you get if you run `ftype Python.File` from your `cf_exec cmd.exe`?

Comment: It says `Python.file="C:\Windows\py.exe" "%L" %*`

Comment: So the `Can't find a default Python` error is only being returned when trying to call further python scripts from within the initial python script?

Comment: I don't have a suitable environment to test this, but it sounds like you might need to use `os.system(sys.executable + "example.py 2 2 0 1")` or `os.system("python example.py 2 2 0 1")`

Comment: Yup that's correct, only when I'm trying to call a python script from within the initial script. Your suggestion seems to have solved the problem - I ended up going with `os.system("python example.py 2 2 0 1")`. If you copy that comment into an answer, I'll mark it as the correct one. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Can't find a default Python` error is only being returned when trying to call further python scripts from within the initial python script - ie if your `ftype` and `PATH` settings are known to be good - then the issue is with the new context, try:

`os.system(sys.executable + "example.py 2 2 0 1")`

or

`os.system("python example.py 2 2 0 1")`