# How do I turn a Python program into a CLI without having to type python3 to execute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, command-line-interface

Instead of typing

```
$ python3 Program.py -<flags> arguments, etc
```

I want to be able to DL the git clone and then be able to type

```
$ Program -<flags> arguments, etc 
# program name without the .py extension
```

I've seen other programs have .yaml files, req.txt files and dockerized them but I can't find anything that shows me how to do this. All the tutorials and guides have stopped short of how to make them simple command line programs.

I've done all the argparse, etc but I'm looking for a guide or some instruction of how to dockerize it and simply run it without having to nav to the dest folder

Comment: I'm using a Mac and a Linux system by the way. I know Windows may have a different method but I can figure that out later when I need it.

Comment: for a unix, you just make program.py executable (`chmod +x program.py`) and add a shebang on top of the file: `#! /usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git itself, so I snipped off the [tag:git] tag.

Answer (score 5):

If you're thinking about distributing the program, you should probably add CLI entry points in your package's `setup.py` file.

For example:

#### Project structure

```
ROOT/
- setup.py
- src/
    - program.py
```

#### `src/program.py`

```
# program.py

def main():
    pass
```

#### `setup.py`

```
# setup.py

from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='my_program',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'Program=src.program:main'
        ]
    }
)
```

The important bit is the line `'Program=src.program:main'`: it associates the name `Program` (the name to invoke from the command line) with the function `main` of `src/program.py`.

Note that this name could be anything - it doesn't necessarily need to be related to your package name, python file names, etc.

You can perform a local installation of your package in order to test this.

From the `ROOT` directory, type `$ pip install -e .` Afterwards, typing

```
$ Program
```

in the terminal **from any directory** will execute the `main` function from `src/program.py`.

This behaviour is the same if anyone `pip install`s your package over PyPI, instead of your local installation.

Answer (score 1):

Add the shebang to the top of the file:

```
#!/bin/python3  # or wherever your python binary is
```

If you have that, then you could do:

```
./Program.py -<flags> arguments etc
```

Comment: Only if you chmod +x

Comment: More likely they'd have to do `./Program.py ...`. Current dir is not normally in the PATH.