# How to write on and export a python file in bash?

Tags: python, bash, file, export

I have a bash script that edits some values in a python file called prova.py and export it to another directory using a while loop. The problem is that when I try to open the prova.py files, some are python files (text/x-python) and some are plain text documents (text/plain). This happens randomly, as if I run the script multiple times some files are in python and then the next run they are as text.

I tried to substitute ${file} in the last cat with prova.py but this doesn't seem to change the results

```
#!/bin/bash
path='/home/students/gbroilo/Desktop/Script'
file='prova.py'

step_x=1
while [ $step_x -lt 5 ]; do  #maximum value of x
  step_y=1
  while [ $step_y -lt 4 ]; do   #maximum value of y
    cp -rf ${path}/Template ${path}/Template_${step_x}_${step_y}      #copy folder and rename it with variable step x and y
    cd ${path}/Template_${step_x}_${step_y}                           #change directory and open the Template folder

    x=$( cat ${file} | sed -n '/x=[^0-9]*/p' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' )   #isolate the value of the x coordinate
    x=$( expr ${x} + ${step_x} )                                      #define the increment of the x coordinate
    y=$( cat ${file} | sed -n '/y=[^0-9]*/p' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' )   #isolate the value of the y coordinate
    y=$( expr ${y} + ${step_y} )                                      #define the increment of the y coordinate

    cat ${file} | sed "s/x=[0-9]*/x=${x}/g" | sed "s/y=[0-9]*/y=${y}/g" > prova.py   #substitute the old value of x and y with their new incremented value
    step_y=$(( ${step_y} + 1 )) #increment by one the current value of y
  done
  step_x=$(( ${step_x} + 1 )) #increment by one the current value of x
done
```

All the exported prova.py files should be Type: Python script (text/x-python)

Comment: does the file have a shebang line? like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take and what program are you using to open the file?

Comment: I have #!/bin/bash at the beginning of the script. The files should be opened with Text Editor and the file does not have any shebang

Comment: The python scripts should have a python shebang?

Comment: No it shouldn't the file I use as a template is automatically exported from a FEA software and doesn't have any shebang at the beginning

Comment: The thing is that some of the exported file are fine and some not, I dont know why :(

Comment: add a python shebang to the beginning of the python script, does the error still occur?

Comment: which one should I add? This one #!/usr/bin/env python ?

Comment: If the python scrips have a `.py` extension you can iterate through them with `for f in $(find . -name "*.py" ); do echo "$f"; done`

Comment: Should I add this command in my script before I do the editing with cat and sed? Is there a way to not add another for loop?

Comment: Without a [mcve], it is impossible to test your script and test our potential solutions.

Comment: Nic3500 I wrote the entire script in the question, do you mean that I should add the prova.py too?