# Mapping a custom a CLI command to a Python script

Tags: python, bash, shell, command-line

I have a python script, let's call it `my_script.py`. The script is supposed to generate simulated responses to an api call performed on the command line.

What I am looking for is some way to have a custom command line command, e.g. `run-my-script` execute `my_script.py` while allowing for `my_script.py` to accept keyword arguments.

It would be great to have a solution that doesn't require external libraries and that allows for keyword arguments to be passed from the command line to that function.

Is there a way to have a custom command on the command line, like `run-my-script` trigger my_script.py?

Though it would be easiest to just run `python my_script.py` from the command line, for my use case I need to have the python script triggered just by `run-my-script` alone.

Comment: You can rename your script to `run-my-script` if you already have the shebang line, then copy it to somewhere on your path.

Comment: Like a shell script named `run-my-script` that itself runs `python3 my_script.py "$@"`?

Comment: @jarmod That is probably one solution. But it seems like more work than necessary since you can run `my_script.py` directly without a shell script wrapper.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice agreed, if the only thing the shell script does is exec the Python script. I figured it might be more complex than that, but maybe it isn’t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alias run-my-script="python my_script.py"

Run this command in terminal and run-my-script will execute my_script.py.

You can also add it in  ~/.bashrc  so you can access it after you reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You should first add a [shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take) to your Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Then you can run it directly from the command line as

```
$ my_script.py
```

If you want the command to be something else, then just rename your file. If you want to run it from any directory, copy it to a directory that is already in you `PATH` or add it's parent directory to your `PATH`.