# Shebang line in Python

Tags: python-3.x, shebang

I typed a simple program of if-else loop in PyCharm without the Shebang line, but I got the output. I came across about the Shebang line a few minutes back. Hence, I would like to know when to use the Shebang line and for what kind of programs should we use Shebang line?

Comment: Take a look athi this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I put #! (shebang) in Python scripts, and what form should it take?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take)