# pass json string from ansible ouput to python in the same ansible playbook

Tags: json, python-3.x, ansible

I have 2 scripts `a.py` and `b.py`.

I have an ansible playbook which runs `a.py` and `b.py`. Here is the script
**Output** of `a.py` is given to `b.py`. The problem is the **Ouput** of `a.py` is a list which can be indexed but whenever I pass the yaml's `stdout` to `b.py` as command line argument it takes as `str` object and it can be indexed as before i.e like `a.py`'s.

**script a.py**

```py
a = [{
        "name": "jack",
        "date": "Jan-06-2021",
        "age": "24",
    },
    {
        "name": "jack1",
        "date": "Jan-07-2021",
        "age": "25",
    },
]
print(a)
```

**b.py script**

```py
import sys
import json
random_variable = sys.argv[1] 
print(json.loads(random_variable)) # tried this no use
```

I want to parse the values of `a` just like `random_variab.e[0]` and `random_variable[1]`.
`random_variable[0]` could be like:

```json
{'name': 'jack', 'date': 'Jan-06-2021', 'age': '24'}
```

```yaml
- name: testing
  gather_facts: True
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: run python script
      command: python3 /test-repo/test_python/a.py
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        var1: "{{result.stdout}}"
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{var1}}"
    
    - name: run python script2
      command: python3 /test-repo/test_python/b.py {{var1}}
      register: result
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{result}}"
```

Error I am getting now

```
["Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File \"/test-repo/test_python/b.py\", line 4, in <module>", "    print(json.loads(a))", "  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py\", line 354, in loads", "    return _default_decoder.decode(s)", " 
 File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py\", line 339, in decode", "    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())", "  File 
\"/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py\", line 355, in raw_decode", "    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)", "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)"]
```

Expected output when I print

```py
random_variable = sys.argv[1]
print(random_variable[0])
```

Output I need

```json
{'name': 'jack', 'date': 'Jan-06-2021', 'age': '24'}
```

Comment: What is the current result?

Comment: Have a look at new edit

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not coming from *b.py*, like you seem to think it is.

It is actually coming from the fact that *a.py* is not printing a JSON, but a python dictionary, and so, you cannot load it back in *b.py* as a JSON.

Debugging the result of *a.py* in the playbook will give you:

```
[{'name': 'jack', 'date': 'Jan-06-2021', 'age': '24'}, {'name': 'jack1', 'date': 'Jan-07-2021', 'age': '25'}]
```

But this is **not** a valid JSON array because, as the error message prompts it to you, string and properties, in JSON, have to be enclosed in **double quotes** not simple ones.

So there is at least two things you should do:

1. Adapt *a.py* and make it read

   ```py
   import json
   a = [{
           "name": "jack",
           "date": "Jan-06-2021",
           "age": "24",
       },
       {
           "name": "jack1",
           "date": "Jan-07-2021",
           "age": "25",
       },
   ]
   print(json.dumps(a))
   ```
2. Adapt your playbook and enclose your JSON string in simple quotes, to not break the shell:

   ```yaml
   - command: python3 /test-repo/test_python/b.py '{{ var1 }}'
   ```

---

This said, I would also make this adaptation: using the proper [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take) in your Python scripts, so you don't have to specify the interpreter on the `command` task anymore.

So *a.py* become:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
a = [{
        "name": "jack",
        "date": "Jan-06-2021",
        "age": "24",
    },
    {
        "name": "jack1",
        "date": "Jan-07-2021",
        "age": "25",
    },
]
print(json.dumps(a))
```

*b.py* become:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import json
print(json.loads(sys.argv[1])[0])
```

Your playbook becomes:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - command: /test-repo/test_python/a.py
      register: result

    - debug: 
        var: result.stdout
    
    - command: /test-repo/test_python/b.py '{{ result.stdout }}'
      register: result

    - debug: 
        var: result.stdout
```

And all this yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [command] ******************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result.stdout": [
        {
            "age": "24",
            "date": "Jan-06-2021",
            "name": "jack"
        },
        {
            "age": "25",
            "date": "Jan-07-2021",
            "name": "jack1"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [command] ******************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result.stdout": {
        "age": "24",
        "date": "Jan-06-2021",
        "name": "jack"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: yeah you are correct, but I have function generation that kind of list, whereas here the list i am passing in a.py takes a string but my the function that generating this kind of list is not passing through json.dump(variable_having_list).

```

```

Comment: File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py\", line 339, in decode", "    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())", "  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py\", line 357, in raw_decode", "    raise JSONDecodeError(\"Expecting value\", s, err.value) from None", "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

****I am getting the following error****

Comment: `json.dumps`! Mind the **s**, `json.dump` is not the same function.