# cant read python3 library in in nifi executestreamcommand

Tags: apache-nifi

i want to use ExecuteStreamCommand in nifi for running a python script say script.py

my script has declared #!/usr/bin/python3

but its not able to read library from python3

I am able to run the script as python3 script.py but cant same on ExecuteStreamCommand of nifi

[image]

anyone has the solution

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Matt's answer

You can point directly to the python3 bin from ExecuteStreamCommand

e.g.

Command path: `/usr/bin/python3`

Command arguments: `/path/to/script.py;x;y;`

Secondly, you should not use `#!/usr/bin/python3` as a Python3 shebang, instead using `#!/usr/bin/env python3` - see here
[Should I put #! (shebang) in Python scripts, and what form should it take?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take)

Answer (score 0):

In your example above you are not invoking `python3` directly, which is what ExecuteStreamCommand expects (the script path should be an argument). The environment used by NiFi may not be the same as the one you use from a Terminal program, and looking into a file for the shebang line is likely a feature of your shell, which may not be available to the NiFi JVM when executing an external process.