# shell script execute python code as shell script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I would like to execute hello.py using test.sh.  However, it seems test.sh read hello.py as sh file.

error message

```
line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `'hello''
```

test.sh

```
#!/user/bin/ python (which python path)
ARRAY=(1 2 3 4)
for num in ${ARRAY[@]}; do
    /artic/m-yasunaga/work/korin-3/src/example/hi.py
    echo $num"th loop"
done
```

hello.py

```
print('hello')
```

When I changed  print('hello') to echo hello, it worked perfectly.

How can I execute hello.py as python code? ( I use linux )

Comment: Your python script needs a shebang line (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take)). Also, your shell script should have a *shell* shebang, not one referring to python (and it cannot contain parenthetical remarks, nor spaces in the middle of the path). The shebang line that starts a script indicates how to run *that script*, not others it may run. The file extension (like .sh or .py) is ignored when you run a script directly like this.

Comment: Actually, since your shell script uses an array (which is a bash extension, not available in all other shells), you should use a bash shebang (like `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`), not a generic shell shebang (like `#!/bin/sh`).

Comment: `/user/bin/ python`?  That's ... bizarre.  Try `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: @JennyRowland : Adding to the comment given by Pursell, your Script is Shell, not Python. Trying to construct a #!-line for Python is even more bizarre....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax errors etc in your scripts.....try this:

Create the following two scripts.

Name: test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ARRAY=(1 2 3 4)
for num in ${ARRAY[@]}; do
    ./hello.py
    echo $num"th loop"
done
```

Name: hello.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print('hello')
```

From your command line, run the following

```
chmod 700 test.sh ;  chmod 700 hello.py
```

Now from the command line, you can run:

```
./test.sh
```

The output will be:

```
>./test.sh 
hello
1th loop
hello
2th loop
hello
3th loop
hello
4th loop
```

Comment: It doesn't matter much here, but I'd also recommend double-quoting the variable references (`for num in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do` and `echo "${num}th loop"`).

Answer (score 0):

You should mention the python path

```
#!/user/bin/ python (which python path)
```

in hello.py file and make it executable using

```
chmod +x hello.py
```

Now you can use it as a executable.