# What is meaning of bash command python3 ./deployment/generators/generatePKGlist.py --file app-pkg.yml

Tags: python, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I am trying to make sense of following line in one of the bash script

```
python3 ./deployment/generators/generatePKGlist.py --file app-pkg.yml
```

Specially, What is meaning of '--file app-pkg.yml' in above line?

Answer (score 0):

It runs the python module and passes the --file as key and app-pkg.yml as the value of the file to that module(./deployment/generators/generatePKGlist.py) as a parameter for running the module.

Answer (score 0):

It's running the python script `generatePKGlist.py` passing command line arguments `--file app-pkg.yml`.

As you tagged `unix`, having the corresponding [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take) and correct execution permission on the file turns specifying the interpreter unnecessary.

Verify if the shebang is there or add it otherwise (first line)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
```

and

```
chmod +x ./deployment/generators/generatePKGlist.py
```

then you can just run

```
./deployment/generators/generatePKGlist.py --file app-pkg.yml
```