# Use crontab with python for write in a file.txt

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

I have a problem with crontab.
My file `sondeCpu.py` has a script to return me the cpu-load percentage. I want the result every minute and I want the output to go to my file `Sample.txt`

```
01 * * * * python3 /home/z/sondeCpu.py >> /home/z/Sample.txt 2&1
```

The script in sondeCpu.py work well alone in the terminal but in crontab the output does not want to go in Sample.txt.

I need some help Thanks you !

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71360478/what-is-meaning-of-bash-command-python3-deployment-generators-generatepkglist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it working with "2>&1" instead of "2&1" ?
Also, for performing it every minute use "*/1" instead of "1". With your version it would be executed in the first minute of every hour.

```
*/1 * * * * python3 /home/z/sondeCpu.py >> /home/z/Sample.txt 2>&1
```

(Ref. crontab https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Cron )