# VisualStudioCode & AtomIO powershell

Tags: powershell, atom-editor

**print.py : The term 'print.py' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.**
At line:1 char:1

- print.py
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (print.py:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

**Suggestion [3,General]: The command print.py was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\print.py". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.**

Hi guys i got this problem in my visual studio code and i got same problem when i downloaded atom.io as the terminal. I want to run my codes concurrently with the terminal and the ide editor but i get this error.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you cannot run your script directly as PowerShell doesn't know how to interprete it. Instead, you should use `python3 print.py` or similar.

On POSIX platforms, you can also prepend a [she-bang comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take) to your script.