# Python shebang with conda

Tags: python, conda, shebang

Following [best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19305076/6619692) I have started an executable Python script with a shebang *specific* to Python 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import spotipy

# ...some fancy code
```

One `chmod +x` later, I'm executing this script as `./quick_example.py` but alas the executable found (running locally on my Mac) is not the Python executable in my active Conda environment, as running `which python3` in my Bash shell throws up `/usr/bin/python3` instead of the desired `/Users/anilkeshwani/opt/miniconda3/envs/spot/bin/python` given by `which python`.

Apparently using `#!/usr/bin/env python` is bad practice in general, so my question is: can I keep the Python 3-specific shebang and somehow have Conda alias `python3` calls when an env is active?

Comment: "Apparently using #!/usr/bin/env python is bad practice in general" where did you read this?

Comment: The problem with using `/usr/bin/env` is that it depends on the user's `$PATH`, so different users may get different versions of Python. You should use the actual path to `python`, e.g. `#!/usr/bin/python3` @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I'm not sure what you've read. Unfortunately, the naming convention across *nix platforms is a total mess. IMO, `python` should just always be Python 3, since Python 2 is passed the EOL. But this is above my pay grade. In any case, looking at [PEP 394](https://peps.python.org/pep-0394/):

> For scripts that are only expected to be run in an activated virtual
> environment, shebang lines can be written as `#!/usr/bin/env python`, as
> this instructs the script to respect the active virtual environment.

It gets messy for scripts not expected to be run in a virtual environment.

TL:DR

Just use `#!/usr/bin/env python`

##### Edit

Ah, looking at the answer you linked to, they were referencing and old version of PEP 394 which has been revised several times since that answer was posted. A total mess, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Noting [the answer by juanpa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74945164/5410751), I think your problem may be in that you haven't activated your conda environment in the shell in which you are running `./quick_example.py`.

Activating a conda environment is done by running `source activate <envname>`. Just creating the env isn't enough, you have to activate it as well before it takes effect. This has to be done each time you create a new shell, although IDEs often have ways to have this be done automatically.

Comment: Nope, it's active as implied in my question "`which python3` in my Bash shell throws up `/usr/bin/python3` instead of the desired `/Users/anilkeshwani/opt/miniconda3/envs/spot/bin/python` given by `which python`", i.e. the fact that `which python` finds an executable inside miniconda/envs (miniconda's default location). Thanks all the same though